# What is the difference between apt and apt-get?

Tags: apt

I read about the new fancy progress bar which was added to `apt` 1.0 in [Softpedia](http://news.softpedia.com/news/APT-1-0-Is-Out-After-16-Years-Gets-Simplified-Commands-and-Color-Output-436124.shtml?utm_source=ForumSoftpedia&utm_medium=ForumSoftpedia&utm_campaign=ForumSoftpedia) and how to enable it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445245/how-do-i-enable-fancy-apt-colours-and-progress-bars). However on running `sudo apt-get update`, I did not see the fancy progress bars. On reading the second link again, the solution explicitly requires you to use `sudo apt update`.

Hence my question is the difference between `apt` and `apt-get`. I thought they were one and the same.

Comment: AFAIK they are only available in Trusty.  Here is how to enable them: http://askubuntu.com/questions/445245/how-do-i-enable-fancy-apt-colours-and-progress-bars

Comment: given that @Seth 's comment is almost 2 years old, I thought I would add now that it is available, installed and usable out of the box. Nothing is required to enable them, just use `apt` instead of `apt-get` (I'm on 15.10)

Comment: apt-get is legacy command and new version is apt.

Comment: @SalmanAmintabar apt-get is not legacy, it should be using in script. apt is better for the user

Answer (score 685, accepted):

They are very similar command line tools available in [Trusty (14.04)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) and later.  `apt-get` and `apt-cache`'s most commonly used commands are available in `apt`.

`apt-get` may be considered as lower-level and "back-end", and support other APT-based tools. `apt` is designed for end-users (human) and its output may be changed between versions.

Note from apt(8):

```
The `apt` command is meant to be pleasant for end users and does not need
       to be backward compatible like apt-get(8).
```

Take a look at this post for more information on the new tool:

- http://mvogt.wordpress.com/2014/04/04/apt-1-0/

#### A synopsis of the above link (with [corrections](https://mvogt.wordpress.com/2014/04/04/apt-1-0/#comment-3357)*****):

> The big news for this version is that we included a new “apt” binary that combines the most commonly used commands from apt-get and apt-cache. The commands are the same as their apt-get/apt-cache counterparts but with slightly different configuration options.

Currently the apt binary supports the following commands:

- **list**: which is similar to `dpkg list` and can be used with flags like
  `--installed` or `--upgradable`.
- **search**: works just like `apt-cache search` but sorted alphabetically.
- **show**: works like `apt-cache show` but hide some details that people are less likely to care about (like the hashes). The full record is still available via `apt-cache show` of course.
- **update**: like the regular `apt-get update` with color output enabled, but `apt update` also shows the number of upgradeable packages (if any).
- **install,remove**: adds progress output during the dpkg run.
- **upgrade**: the same as `apt-get upgrade --with-new-pkgs`.*****
- **full-upgrade**: a more meaningful name for `dist-upgrade`.
- **edit-sources**: edit `sources.list` using `$EDITOR`.
- **policy**: works just like `apt-cache policy`

You can enable/disable the install progress [bar] via:

```
# echo 'Dpkg::Progress-Fancy "1";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99progressbar
```

Comment: Just curious - isn't apt upgrade equivalent to 'upgrade --with-new-pkgs' (instead of dist-upgrade which IIRC does it by default and also removes)?

Comment: Strangely `apt upgrade` gives me an error where `apt-get upgrade` only prints a warning when a PPA does not have a  Release file.

Comment: [That blog post](http://mvogt.wordpress.com/2014/04/04/apt-1-0/) is [mistaken](https://mvogt.wordpress.com/2014/04/04/apt-1-0/#comment-3357) to say `apt upgrade` is like `apt-get dist-upgrade --with-new-pkgs`. `dist-upgrade` can install new packages *and can remove them*. UI aside, `apt upgrade` is `apt-get upgrade --with-new-pkgs`. See [JungleMartin's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/674479) and [apt(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/apt.8.html) on `upgrade`: "New packages will be installed if required to satisfy dependencies, but existing packages will never be removed."

Comment: May be worth mentioning that starting in 16.04 by default  apt does not save the downloaded packages while apt-get does.

Comment: Another nicety of `apt` if you have installation running already, and you execute `apt-get install foo`, it will bail out with `E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend)`. `apt` on the other hand will block with an interactive timeout counter till the other installation process is finished.

Comment: @Hi-Angel: Was one of the "apt" in your last comment meant to be an "apt-get"?

Comment: @EricS I don't think so. I don't remember details, but judging by the content of the comment, the "installation running" might be by anything: `apt`, `apt-get`, plain `dpkg`. That is because the lock `/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend` is the dpkg lock. And then I describe the difference in behavior, where `apt` just blocks till installation finishes, whereas `apt-get` bails out.

Comment: `apt: WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.`

Comment: what is the `(8)` in the answer?

Comment: @Gulzar it indicates the section of the manual in which the command is explained. In this case it's Section 8: administration and privileged commands

Comment: To add to what kikones34 said: the man(1) command can take a second (or rather, a first argument ;-)): man 8 apt.  This is important if there are two man pages with the same name in different sections.

Answer (score 145):

As I write this, [the `apt` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man8/apt.8.html) (my apt package version: 1.0.1ubuntu2.8) includes the following section:

```
DIFFERENCES TO APT-GET(8)
   The apt command is meant to be pleasant for end users and does not need
   to be backward compatible like apt-get(8). Therefore some options are
   different:

   ·   The option DPkg::Progress-Fancy is enabled.
   ·   The option APT::Color is enabled.
   ·   A new list command is available similar to dpkg --list.
   ·   The option upgrade has --with-new-pkgs enabled by default.
```

Comment: This is the correct answer (for Debian and Ubuntu as well as other derivatives like Mint). In particular, running `sudo apt upgrade` will perform the same operations as `sudo apt-get upgrade --with-new-pkgs`. It will install new packages but, *unlike* `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, it will not remove old ones (except when installing a new version of the *same* package, of course--which `sudo apt-get upgrade` will also do). [`man apt`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/apt.8.html) further corroborates that this answer is correct.

Comment: I'm rolling back your rollback of my edit because a) your formatting requires unnecessary scrolling, and b) your copied text is incorrect, the option isn't `DPkgPM::...`, but `DPkg::..`, as the online manpage shows.

Comment: bonus points for RTFM

Comment: The option "check" doesn't work with apt. I have to use "apt-get check". Why?

Comment: This answer is (of course, _sigh_) outdated.  In the current version of apt (2.5.6 in unstable), this section isn't present anymore.

Comment: @Juan Because check is very obviously not something an average user should need to use.

Answer (score 61):

There are various tools that interact with [Advanced Packaging Tool (APT)](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/apt.html.en) and allow you to install, remove and manage packages in [Debian based Linux distributions](https://www.debian.org/derivatives/). `apt-get` is one such command-line tool which is widely popular. Another popular tool is [Aptitude](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/aptitude.html.en) with both GUI and command-line options.

If you have used `apt-get` commands, you might have come across a number of similar commands such as `apt-cache`, `apt-config` etc. And this is where the problem arises.

You see, these commands are way too low level and they have so many functionalities which are perhaps never used by an average Linux user. On the other hand, the most commonly used package management commands are scattered across `apt-get`, `apt-cache` and `apt-config`.

The `apt` commands have been introduced to solve this problem. `apt` consists some of the most widely used features from `apt-get`, `apt-cache` and `apt-config` leaving aside obscure and seldom used features.

With `apt`, you don’t have to fiddle your way from `apt-get` to `apt-cache` to `apt-config`. `apt` is more structured and provides you with necessary options needed to manage packages.

**Bottom line:** `apt` = most common used command options from `apt-get`, `apt-cache` and `apt-config`.

I have written in detail on the [difference between apt and apt-get](https://itsfoss.com/apt-vs-apt-get-difference/).

Answer (score 25):

APT is a vast project, whose original plans included a graphical interface. It is based on a library which contains the core application, and apt-get is the first front end — command-line based — which was developed within the project.

> `apt` is a second command-line based front end provided by APT which overcomes some design mistakes of `apt-get`.

Quoted from:

https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.apt-get.html