# When updating, is using "sudo apt-get update" the same as using the GUI update on desktop?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, updates, update-manager

Is using `sudo apt-get update` the same as using the GUI update on the desktop?

Comment: `sudo apt-get update` merely refreshes your software list with updates and new packages. The GUI does that same thing, but also tells you about new updates and lets you install them. `sudo apt-get upgrade` is what will update your packages.

Answer (score 2):

If you do the command line updates, there are a couple of extra steps:

`sudo apt-get update` updates the libraries such that your computer can tell what packages are outdates

`sudo apt-get upgrade` upgrades most packages

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` upgrades packages which require greater system modification.

A combination of `... update` followed by `... dist-upgrade` and then `sudo reboot` is the same as the gui

There is a very good link to the apt-get upgrade commands [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/502981/understanding-various-update-and-upgrade-commands)

Comment: This answer makes this iteration of this question the ideal one!