# How to install Android Studio on Ubuntu?

Tags: android-studio

Please tell me the full process of installing Android Studio and its necessary dependencies.

Comment: Simply install [`umake`](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-desktop/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntu-make) and [run `umake android --accept-license`](http://askubuntu.com/a/677805/4490).

Comment: umake work but I needed to remove jdk 9 umake installed jdk 8 and the version in 16.10 don't work because google change checksum from sha1 to sha256 but the version from github work.

Comment: This tutorial will help you - https://androidwave.com/install-android-studio-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 223):

### Installing Java

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

After that

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

> **Note:** WebUpd8 team's PPA has been discontinued with effective from April 16, 2019. Thus this PPA doesn't have any Java files. More information can be found on [PPA's page on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java). Hence this method no longer works and exists because of historical reasons.

---

### Installing Android Studio

1. Download Android Studio from [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), use *All Android Studio Packages*
2. Extract the archive file into an appropriate location for your applications, eg: `/opt`. Use the filename of your downloaded archive, in my example `android-studio-ide-141.2178183-linux.zip`

   ```
   sudo unzip android-studio-ide-141.2178183-linux.zip -d /opt
   ```
3. To launch Android Studio, navigate to the `/opt/android-studio/bin` directory in a terminal and execute `./studio.sh`. Or use a desktop file, see below.

   You may want to add `/opt/android-studio/bin` to your PATH environmental variable so that you can start Android Studio from any directory.

---

### Create a desktop file

Create a new file `androidstudio.desktop` by running the command:

`nano ~/.local/share/applications/androidstudio.desktop`

and add the lines below

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Android Studio
Exec="/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh" %f
Icon=/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.png
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=android-studio
```

---

### Installing Android SDK (if necessary)

1. **Click the marked button**

   [image]
2. **Get the latest SDK tools**

   As a minimum when setting up the Android SDK, you should download the latest tools and Android platform:

   1. Open the Tools directory and select:

      - Android SDK Tools
      - Android SDK Platform-tools
      - Android SDK Build-tools (highest version)
   2. Open the first Android X.X folder (the latest version) and select:

      - SDK Platform
      - A system image for the emulator, such as 
        ARM EABI v7a System Image
3. **Get the support library for additional APIs**

   The Android Support Library provides an extended set of APIs that are compatible with most versions of Android.

   Open the `Extras` directory and select:

   - Android Support Repository
   - Android Support Library
4. **Get Google Play services for even more APIs**

   To develop with Google APIs, you need the Google Play services package:

   Open the `Extras` directory and select:

   - Google Repository
   - Google Play services
5. **Install the packages**

   Once you've selected all the desired packages, continue to install:

   - Click <kbd>Install X packages</kbd>.
   - In the next window, double-click each package name on the left to accept the license agreement for each.
   - Click <kbd>Install</kbd>.

Comment: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/install-android-studio-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html  -> http://www.webupd8.org/2014/09/canonical-releases-ubuntu-developer.html -> http://www.webupd8.org/2014/12/ubuntu-developer-tools-center-renamed.html

Comment: Doesn't Android Studio require JDK 7? Will oracle-java8 work correctly?

Comment: So is a direct download of android-studio still the best way or is there a more normal apt-get install way?

Comment: What does this "sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default" command do?
After "sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
" if i fire "javac version" i get javac version and i feel that java is installed.then what does the above command do?
Please tell me if i am missing something?

Comment: When I run the command `./studio.sh`, it throws exception: `Error: Could not find or load main class com.intellij.idea.Main`. Can you please help?

Comment: This seems to be outdated on Ubuntu 18.10: `Package oracle-java8-installer is not available, but is referred to by another package.
`

Comment: Java instructions for Ubuntu 18 https://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-11-ubuntu-18-04-bionic/

Comment: As noted [here](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java), the webupd8 java ppa is discontinued and no longer hosts any content for installing java due to changes Oracle made in the license agreement in April 2019.

Comment: Is this answer up to date for Ubuntu 18.04 in 2020?

Comment: One can also create a desktop entry via the app itself: Tools -> Create Desktop Entry

Comment: This answer is presently outdated. For new users, please refer to the official guide here: https://developer.android.com/studio/install

Comment: Is this still updated? How about 2021 updates?

Answer (score 69):

The easiest method to install Android Studio on Ubuntu is to just use the [snap package](https://snapcraft.io/android-studio) from Ubuntu Software store. No need to download Android Studio as zip, try to manually install it, run umake and other scripts, add PPAs or fiddle with Java installation. This snap package bundles the latest Android Studio along with OpenJDK and all the necessary dependencies. Neat and clean!

### Step 1: Install Android Studio

Search *"android studio"* in Ubuntu Software, select the first entry that shows up and install it:

[image: Search Android Studio on Ubuntu Software]
[image: Android Studio on Ubuntu Software]

Or if you prefer the command line way, run this in *Terminal*:

```
sudo snap install --classic android-studio
```

### Step 2: Install Android SDK

Open the newly installed Android Studio from dashboard:

[image: Android Studio app on Dash]

Don't need to import anything if this is the first time you're installing it:

[image: Import Dialog]

The Setup Wizard'll guide you through installation:

[image: Android Studio Setup Wizard]

Select *Standard* install to get the latest SDK and *Custom* in-case you wanna change the SDK version or its install location. From here on, it's pretty straightforward, just click next-next and you'll have the SDK downloaded and installed.

[image: Select Standard or Custom installation]

### Step 3: Setting PATHs (Optional)

This step might be useful if you want Android SDK's developer tool commands like *adb*, *fastboot*, *aapt*, etc available in *Terminal*. Might be needed by 3rd party dev platforms like React Native, Ionic, Cordova, etc and other tools too. For setting PATHs, edit your `~/.profile` file:

```
gedit ~/.profile
```

and then add the following lines to it:

```
# Android SDK Tools PATH
export ANDROID_HOME=${HOME}/Android/Sdk
export PATH="${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:${PATH}"
export PATH="${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator:${PATH}"
export PATH="${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools:${PATH}"
```

If you changed SDK location at the end of Step 2, don't forget to change the line `export ANDROID_HOME=${HOME}/Android/Sdk` accordingly. Do a **restart** (or just logout and then log back in) for the PATHs to take effect.

---

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS & 16.04 LTS. Should technically work on any Ubuntu version with snap support (16.04 LTS and newer). Would work on 14.04 LTS too if you [install support for snap packages first](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/02/install-snap-apps-ubuntu-14-04).

Comment: Nothing wrong with this answer, but unfortunately on Ubuntu 17.04 there currently seems to be a bug: http://ubuntu-bugs.narkive.com/76PQCtx9/bug-1697225-new-cannot-install-android-studio-in-17-04 At least, unmake fails for me. Until that gets fixed, I assume the only workaround is to download the zip file and install it manually.

Comment: while running `ubuntu-make.umake android` got an error 'Segmentation fault`

Comment: It's easier to just use the snap package as described by this updated answer, instead of `umake` or manual install

Comment: using Snap and symlink to non-Snap location: `locate studio.sh` => `/snap/android-studio/126/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`.. `ln -s /snap/android-studio/126/android-studio /usr/local/android-studio` Also using `apt install sdkmanager`.. `export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/lib/android-sdk`

Answer (score 49):

[@A.B's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/634085/2355) is correct and complete. I just add that alternatively you can easily install an up-to-date Android Studio using Canonical's [Ubuntu Make](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make).

#### Installing Ubuntu Make :

**For Ubuntu 14.04LTS**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ubuntu-make
```

**For Ubuntu 15.10 and up**

Ubuntu Make is already in official repositories, run :

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-make
```

**Note** that **umake version** should be **16.05** to be able to download android studio, check by running

```
umake --version
```

If not, use the Ubuntu 14.04 method to install it.

---

#### Installing Android Studio :

```
umake android
```

There may be an error message related to license that may be corrected using an additional parameter:

```
umake android --accept-license
```

#### Uninstall Android Studio :

```
umake android --remove
```

Comment: Hey hg8. Is this a full installation of the android studio? All components that are required come with it too such as Java?

Comment: Hello @Elysium. I just tried on a fresh Ubuntu 15.10 installation. Ubuntu `make` automatically install everything required. Nothing more are needed ;) (for info it currently install OpenJDK 1.7).

Comment: This isn't working for me on Ubuntu 15.10; I keep getting "ERROR: We were expecting to find a license on the download page, we didn't."

Comment: @APerson try  `umake android --accept-license` [as suggested in a different question](http://askubuntu.com/a/755830/28076).

Comment: Did you mean to write `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: @ivarni No. Please see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445384/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-and-apt-get) ;)

Comment: 16.04 getting `ERROR: A default framework for category Android was requested where there is none
usage: umake android [-h] {android-ndk} ...`

Comment: @MichaelDurrant: Try updating your umake by executing the "Ubuntu 14.04LTS" step.

Comment: `android-studio: Android Studio (default) [not installable on this machine]` on 19.04

Answer (score 33):

In the eve of 2018, the most voted answer is still awesome, but seems a bit outdated, and as I run into this recently, I decided to share my fresh experience here.

## 1. Installing Java

Since Android Studio 2.2 was released you won’t need to install any JDK yourself in most cases, since it’s brought with the IDE.

[Reference for more details](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html#jdk)

## 2. Installing prerequisite software

The following command should be run in the first place, so we can avoid some problems with the [AVD tool](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html#about) in future:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386
```

[Reference for more details](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html?gclid=CjwKCAiAsejRBRB3EiwAZft7sMHn8RYO8r4Q8mJF-8qrM08Hwvq7CUWzhFC1JxgXvrf4fDqhuYE5JBoCz00QAvD_BwE)

## 3. Downloading and Unpackaging Android Studio

You can get Android Studio archive from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html). Nothing special, just wait until loading is finished :)

Google is a [registered LANANA provider](http://www.lanana.org/lsbreg/providers/providers.txt), so in order to comply the [Linux FSH contract](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.pdf) (part 3.13 /opt) I would like to suggest unpacking the archive to the `google/android-studio` folder:

```
sudo unzip ~/Downloads/android-studio-ide-171.4443003-linux.zip -d /opt/google/
```

#### 3.1 [Optional] Change write permission for Android Studio folder

You may find setting write permissions for all users convenient when it comes to updating Android Studio. However it’s not widely used, and seems to violate the [principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege). However, just in case, if you like this way better just execute in terminal:

```
sudo chmod o+w /opt/google/android-studio/
```

**Alternatively you can always run Android-Studio on behalf of root and performs all updates you need without this step involved**.

## 4. Creating Android SDK directory

I don’t embrace the idea that each user should have his own copy of Android SDK tools (build tools, source codes, system images, etc..) but Android Studio works exactly that way (it's likely because of permissions issue). Let's make it use another folder shared among all users in the system.

#### 4.1 Create directory

Make the android-sdk folder for future use:

```
sudo mkdir /opt/google/android-sdk
sudo chmod o+w /opt/google/android-sdk
```

The last command changes permissions so every user in the system is able to edit this android-sdk folder (installing and removing packages).

#### 4.2 Setting Environment Variables

Android Studio is still pointing to its own path at this moment. To make Android Studio install SDKs in shared folder, we need to specify environment variables. Currently there are two variables pointing to SDK folder: **ANDROID_HOME** and **ANDROID_SDK_ROOT**. The first is deprecated, but Android Studio won’t use ANDROID_SDK_ROOT when launching it first time even if it’s specified, so i would recommend to specify both variables. To keep things consistent and clear, let’s specify them in a separate shell for the android-studio in the [profile.d](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2Fetc.2Fprofile.d.2F.2A.sh) folder (so you can remove them later in case of removing Android Studio):

```
sudo -i
cd /etc/profile.d/
echo export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/opt/google/android-sdk/ > android_studio.sh
echo export ANDROID_HOME=/opt/google/android-sdk/ >> android_studio.sh
```

#### 4.2.1 Setting JAVA_HOME Variable

If you going to use gradlew commands via CLI interface, it will be useful to add JAVA_HOME pointing to embedded JRE (otherwise gradle won't be able to locate it)

```
echo export JAVA_HOME=/opt/google/android-studio/jre >> android_studio.sh
```

Now you need log out the system and log in back to apply this new script.

[Reference for more details](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables.html)

## 5. Installing SDK

Since we changed permissions for the SDK folder (`/opt/google/android-sdk/`), we don’t need any special permissions to write in it. Just run android-studio on behalf of your current user:

```
/opt/google/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
```

Now follow setup wizard instructions. Eventually you will hit Downloading Components window. It may take for a while until required components are installed. As we took care about all required libraries and software from very beginning (part 2), this process should be finished without any error.

[image: Downloading Android SDK]

Upon first launch Android Studio installs only latest SDK platform (at the time of writing API 27). To make your toolset viable, you need at least 2-3 more older SDK platforms installed ([here](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) you can find the dashboard showing actual demand for different APIs version). In order to get them, from the Android Studio welcoming screen, click “Configure” and choose the SDK Manager option.

[image: Android SDK option]

From here you can choose whatever you need to develop Android apps.
P.S. You can actually install everything from the list (even obsolete packages), but it will take ages to download.

## 6. Creating desktop entry

Currently Android Studio offers embedded feature in order to create desktop entry. We need to run Studio with root permissions, so it's possible to do that for all users in the system, :

```
sudo -E /opt/google/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
```

*P.S. -E option is needed to keep our environment variables (ANDROID_HOME/ANDROID_SDK_ROOT) available while sudoing.*

You will have to pass the same Setup Wizard again (it’s being performed for the root user now) and once you hit the Welcoming screen, you can find option Create Desktop Entry from “Configure” menu:

[image: Create Desktop Entry item]

In the dialog box that opens, ensure that “Create the entry for all users” checkbox is checked and click OK.

[image]

Now you can close Android Studio and open from Unity Launcher!

*P.S. For those who are interested in where the entry was created and what is inside, you can find it in `/usr/share/applications/jetbrains-studio.desktop`:*

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Android Studio
Icon=/opt/google/android-studio/bin/studio.png
Exec="/opt/google/android-studio/bin/studio.sh" %f
Comment=The Drive to Develop
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-studio
```

## A. [Bonus] Uninstall script

And for sweets I prepared a shell script that you can use to remove your Android Studio altogether, including SDK folder, settings, emulators and cache folders from all users. It’s tailored for the steps above, but the paths are in the top of the file, so you can easily adapt it for your own configuration. Here we go:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
####################################
#
# Android Studio uninstalling script
#
####################################

# Ensure root permissions

if [ $(whoami) != 'root' ]; then
    echo "Must be root to run $0"
        exit 1;
fi

# Variables

studio_folders=(.android .AndroidStudio* .gradle)   # look for these folders
paths=(/home/,2 /root/,1)                   # in these folders 
studio_path="/opt/google/android-studio/"
sdk_path="/opt/google/android-sdk/"
env_variables="/etc/profile.d/android_studio.sh"

# Functions

deletefolders() {
    local name_expression=( \( -name "${studio_folders[0]}" )
    for (( i=1; i<${#studio_folders[*]}; i++ )); do
        name_expression[${#name_expression[*]}]=-o
        name_expression[${#name_expression[*]}]=-name
        name_expression[${#name_expression[*]}]="${studio_folders[$i]}"
    done
    name_expression[${#name_expression[*]}]=\)

    find "$1" -maxdepth "$2" -type d ${name_expression[*]} -exec rm -rf {} \;
}

# Commands

for path in ${paths[*]}; do
    deletefolders ${path%,*} ${path#*,}
done

rm -r $studio_path
rm -r $sdk_path
rm $env_variables
```

**Please be advised that the wildcard .AndroidStudio* is used in the script to remove settings of different android studio versions. If you keep something valuable in the hidden folder with the name starting with ‘.AndroidStudio’, it’s also gonna be removed.**

For those who not familiar with the notion of shell scripts, here are simple steps that should help:

1. Open terminal, write command nano. A nano editor will be opened in
   terminal window.
2. Copy the text from the script above and past it in
   the terminal window with nano opened (Ctrl+Shift+V)
3. Click Ctrl+O in order to save file, choose the path and name of the file with .sh extension:

   [image: Uninstall script]
4. Exit the nano (ctrl+X)
5. In the terminal you need to apply this command to just created file to make it runnable (supposing you saved your script in `~/Documents` directory and named it android_uninstall.sh):

   ```
   chmod u+x ~/Documents/android_uninstall.sh
   ```
6. Now you can run the script specifying path to it in terminal. Keep in mind that without root permission it won’t remove folders from the `/opt/` directory, so script will ask you for these permissions before doing anything.

That’s it. I’m actually quite new in Linux kind OSs, so feel free to correct me in comments as needed.

Comment: You asked for comments about your answer in an earlier comment which you subsequently deleted, but I'm replying to that comment now anyway. I successfully installed the latest version of Android Studio by following the instructions in your answer. Later I also installed  the latest version of Pycharm IDE and found that it created a new `google` directory in `/opt` the same as Android Studio did. Pycharm didn't use to create a `google` directory, it installed straight into the `/opt` directory. Maybe this is a global change that effects all IDEs that are based on JetBrains software.

Comment: @karel, hey. Thanks for the comment, frankly speaking i could not remember if i asked for it. Anyway, what you described sounds weird - i checked the [PyCharm installation instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/requirements-installation-and-launching.html) and it doesn't seem to install anything without a user directly involved. Could you elaborate on what kind of stuff is going to be installed in `/google` folder in this case? @

Comment: It's similar to installing Android Studio where there are  android-studio and android-sdk folders located inside the `/opt/google` folder, only of course it's for Pycharm, so instead there is a pycharm folder located inside the `/opt/google` folder that contains the installed Pycharm IDE.

Comment: @karel, i'm not quite sure i understand you correctly - PyCharm installation involves extracting files from archive, so you can specify whatever path you want, right? What path do you specify in this command - `tar xfz <pycharm-professional or pycharm-community>-*.tar.gz -C <new_archive_folder>`?

Comment: `tools.jar' seems to be not in Studio classpath.
Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE.`
Got the following error

Comment: @GaganRajput did you get this error when running Gradle from command-line? It seems that Android Studio doesn't pass path to it's JRE anywhere, but you are still able to use all features via UI. If that's not an option, you can complement our android_studio.sh file with JAVA_HOME pointing to embedded JRE (I can check the exact path later today, but you can try find it yourself somewhere in Android Studio folder)

Comment: @GaganRajput sorry for the late answer, please check part 4.2.1, i added a couple of tips how to tailor environment variables to use embedded JRE.

Answer (score 13):

You can install Android Studio by using [Maarten Fonville's PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Emaarten-fonville/+archive/ubuntu/android-studio).

First, add the android-studio repository:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:maarten-fonville/android-studio
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install:

```
sudo apt-get install android-studio
```

More information can be found at https://mfonville.github.io/android-studio/

Comment: This works well and PPA is up to date.

Comment: Yes this PPA is upto date, this should be voted up more!

Comment: Failed for me.  Got an system error then "Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-9-jdk_9~b114-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb"

Comment: In my system `sudo su -` and `torify apt install android-studio` resolve same error. because google restrict Iran ip we cant access to google services.

Comment: Before that run this: https://askubuntu.com/a/772485/678872

Answer (score 6):

If you are running a 64-bit version of Ubuntu (16.04), you need to install some 32-bit libraries with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```

or

`sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6`

So that you don't have this error:

```
Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool.
```

For more read this [doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html)

Comment: except the period ofcourse

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question: how do you install Android Studio on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5):

Quoted from http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/11/install-android-studio-ubuntu-14-04-ppa/

Android Studio depends on Java, and Oracle Java 7 or 8 is recommended

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer oracle-java7-set-default
```

Add the Android Studio PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio
```

Then update package lists and install it:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install android-studio
```

Once installed, start the setup wizard from the Unity Dash or just run command

```
/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
```

Comment: nice one, works perfectly

Comment: Package is broken in Xenial.

Comment: This should be removed. paolorotolo specifically says that it is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

Installing Android Studio on Ubuntu got even easier. We have packaged it as a snap, so you can just install it by

`$ sudo snap install android-studio --classic`

Or just search for `Android Studio` in `Ubuntu Software`.

Answer (score 2):

For ubuntu 16.04, the syntax is as follows.

```
umake android android-ndk [-h] [-r] [--accept-license] [destdir]
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not required that you use a package archive.

#### Installation

- Download the zip file from here:

  https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#linux-bundle
- Extract it some where under `/home/....`
- Run `./bin/sudio.sh`

To create a desktop entry:

```
Go to Android Studio > Tools > Create desktop Entry
```

#### Prerequisites:

OpenJDK comes pre-installed, so use that.

---

Android Studio notifies you with a small bubble dialog when an update is available for the IDE, but you can manually check for updates by clicking `Help > Check for Update`

#### FYI

You can switch between JDKs, by changing the JDK path in the settings. JDKs are installed under `/usr/lib/jvm`

```
$ ls /usr/lib/jvm/
default-java  java-1.5.0-gcj-6-amd64  java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64  java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

Here in my case `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java` is a symlink to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`

So I'd use that as the JDK path in the settings.

Comment: Thank you for posting. I have 2 questions: 1. Which version of OpenJDK comes pre-installed, 8 or 9? 2. If I already have both versions of OpenJDK 8 and 9 installed can I switch back and forth between 8 and 9 in the Android Studio settings, [as it is possible to do with openjdk-8-jdk and openjdk-9-jdk in recent versions of Eclipse IDE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975959/a-problem-installing-eclipse-with-java-9-to-ubuntu/988936#988936)?

Comment: @Eclipse IDE Do a `$ dpkg -l | grep jdk`. Yes you can change the used SDK, JDK from settings.

Comment: This is the best and straight foward solution

Comment: Best answer no need to deal with anything else.

Guys don't forget to vote and not just comment.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio is available as a snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. The Android Studio snap package was the 5th most popular snap package in 2018. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install android-studio --classic
```

[image]

Android Studio provides the fastest tools for building apps on every type of Android device.

World-class code editing, debugging, performance tooling, a flexible build system, and an instant build/deploy system all allow you to focus on building unique and high quality apps.

#### System Requirements for Android Studio

- 8 GB RAM recommended; plus 1 GB for the Android Emulator
- 2 GB of available disk space minimum, 4 GB recommended

Answer (score 1):

Please install toolbox from here and you will have latest Android studio install and update:

[Toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/de-de/toolbox-app/)

Answer (score 0):

1- Run to Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+t) and install JDK:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

to check the java jdk version, type

```
javac -version
```

or

```
java -version
```

2- Download Full bundled ADK from oficial site, unzip it, open it and follow the instructions in install-Linux-tar.txt.

3- Follow the ADK installation Wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up Android Studio takes just a few clicks. (You should have already [downloaded Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html).)

To install Android Studio on Linux, proceed as follows:

1. Unpack the `.zip` file you downloaded to an appropriate location for your applications, such as within `/usr/local/` for your user profile, or `/opt/` for shared users.
2. To launch Android Studio, open a terminal, navigate to the android-studio/bin/ directory, and execute studio.sh.
3. Select whether you want to import previous Android Studio settings or not, then click **OK**.
4. The Android Studio Setup Wizard guides you though the rest of the setup, which includes downloading Android SDK components that are required for development.

> Tip: To make Android Studio available in your list of applications,
>   select Tools > Create Desktop Entry from the Android Studio menu bar.

**Required libraries for 64-bit machines:**
If you are running a 64-bit version of Ubuntu, you need to install some 32-bit libraries with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386
```

If you are running 64-bit Fedora, the command is:

```
sudo yum install zlib.i686 ncurses-libs.i686 bzip2-libs.i686
```

and install `jdk`[**not necessary now, will install automatically**]

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-9-jdk
```

copy of https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html