# I have already downloaded Eclipse from the Software Center but how do I get ADT?

Tags: software-installation, java, eclipse, ide

I went to the Software Center and installled Eclipse. However, I need the Android Developer Tools version. Is there any way I can get that without having to download the whole package (i.e. Eclipse + ADT) all over again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse is not longer supported for Android development. [Download](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) Android Studio instead and follow [these](https://askubuntu.com/a/634085/367165) steps.

The new IDE is built on IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition, the popular Java IDE by JetBrains.

---

Or, if you really need Eclipse, install the Eclipse ADT plugin

1. Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software.
2. Click <kbd>Add</kbd>, in the top-right corner.
3. In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the Name and the following URL for the Location:

   ```
   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
   ```

   **Note**: The Android Developer Tools update site requires a secure connection. Make sure the update site URL you enter starts with HTTPS.
4. Click OK.
5. In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.
6. In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next.
7. Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish.

   If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click <kbd>OK</kbd>.
8. When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.

<sub>[Source](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Download)</sub>

Comment: I know it isn't supported. But I am using it for a course I am enrolled in, so I need ADT. How do you suggest I do that?

Comment: @SR1 Updated my answer

Comment: @SR1 As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As @A.B said, do not forget that Eclipse is not supported anymore.

For people that really need to use Eclipse you can easily install it using Canonical `Ubuntu-make` :

#### Installing Ubuntu Make :

**For Ubuntu 14.04, 14.10 users :**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
```

**For Ubuntu 15.04 and up :**

Ubuntu make is already in official repositories, run :

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
```

---

#### Installing Eclipse :

```
umake ide eclipse
```

#### Uninstall Eclipse :

```
umake ide eclipse --remove
```