# cannot install android studio

Tags: package-management, ppa, android-studio

I tried to install andorid studio with PPA :

But after install running

```
 sudo apt-get install android-studio
```

is giving error :-

```
    Setting up android-studio (4.11.0-ubuntu0) ...
Archive:  /opt/android-studio-ide-141.2117773-linux.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /opt/android-studio-ide-141.2117773-linux.zip or
        /opt/android-studio-ide-141.2117773-linux.zip.zip, and cannot find /opt/android-studio-ide-141.2117773-linux.zip.ZIP, period.
find: `/opt/android-studio/': No such file or directory
find: `/opt/android-studio/': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package android-studio (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 android-studio
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: did you use this PPA : `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio` ?

Comment: @Serphiroth yes !

Comment: Why don't you download the zip file directly from the Android Studio site, and unzip/install it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android studio installation on 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/634082/android-studio-installation-on-14-04)

Answer (score 1):

**How to install Android Studio :**

1 - Download All Android Studio Packages for linux from [here](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/1.3.0.10/android-studio-ide-141.2117773-linux.zip) .

2 - Unpack the downloaded ZIP file into an appropriate location for your applications (for instance, in your home directory).

```
unzip android-studio-ide-141.2117773-linux.zip
```

3 - Go to the `android-studio/bin/` by typing:

```
 cd /home/<user_name>/android-studio/bin/
```

(Replace `<user_name>` by your login user)

4 - And type :

```
sudo chmod u+x studio.sh
```

5 - After pressing enter, you will be prompt for root password, after entering password, hit enter and then type :

```
./studio.sh
```

Source :

- [Installing Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=studio)
- [How to install Android Studio in Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qfinKxwYYZs)

Comment: This is the preferred way. It even asks you to automatically create lauchers

Answer (score 0):

This was a temporary problem. Try it again and it will work. I have installed Android Studio using the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~paolorotolo/+archive/ubuntu/android-studio) in this moment.

This does not mean that the problem can not reoccur.

A complete step-by-step guide to install Android Studio and create a desktop file you can find [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/634085/367165).

Sorry for the short answer, but that's it. **;)**

Comment: Flagged for duplication!  :P