# Running AndroidStudio on Ubuntu 15.10 crash

Tags: java, android, openjdk, 15.10

Right now I am facing the issue that I cannot develop in AndroidStudio using Ubuntu 15.10, because both openjdk-7 and openjdk-8 cause problems.

**openjdk-7 issue**

Running AndroidStudio using `env STUDIO_JDK=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64 /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`

causes the VIRT column of `top` of Xorg to jump to 25.1G while my memory usage seems okay (3.5 of 8 GB used).

However, this causes git-cola to break:

```
$ git-cola
QNativeImage: Unable to attach to shared memory segment. 

(python:13321): Gdk-WARNING **: shmget failed: error 28 (No space left on device)
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0

[...]
```

causing this visual experience:

[image]

Guys at Arch say that this is an openjdk-7 related memory leak: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=201488

**openjdk-8 issue**

When starting AndroidStudio with openjdk-8 (`env STUDIO_JDK=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`) no program's `VIRT` column exceeds 5GB.

But AndroidStudio crashes after some time (often when showing an auto-complete list in XML or Java).

The last crash reason is

```
(java:14046): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /build/glib2.0-ajuDY6/glib2.0-2.46.1/./gobject/gsignal.c:3484: signal name 'bounds_changed' is invalid for instance '0x7fd32c1f01c0' of type 'JawImpl_0'

(java:14046): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /build/glib2.0-ajuDY6/glib2.0-2.46.1/./gobject/gsignal.c:3484: signal name 'bounds_changed' is invalid for instance '0x7fd32c1f01c0' of type 'JawImpl_0'

(java:14046): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /build/glib2.0-ajuDY6/glib2.0-2.46.1/./gobject/gsignal.c:3484: signal name 'bounds_changed' is invalid for instance '0x7fd32c1f01c0' of type 'JawImpl_0'
Okt 29, 2015 9:29:20 PM com.android.tools.idea.monitor.network.NetworkSampler checkStatsFile
WARNUNG: IOException null in ls /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats
```

---

- AndroidStudio version: 1.4.0 and 1.4.1 (Beta)
- OpenJDK8 version: 1.8.0_66-internal
- OpenJDK7 version: 1.7.0_85

I was running AndroidStudio using openjdk-8 without problems using Ubutnu 15.04.

Ideas?

Comment: How did you setup Android Studio?

Comment: @Wilf Downloaded from developer.android.com/sdk/ and extracted to `/opt/android-studio`

Comment: Ok. You could try the PPA version and or the Oracle version of Java mentioned [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/install-android-studio-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634082/android-studio-installation-on-14-04)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to use Oracle Java 8 (as @wilf suggested as well), which works fine for now.

- Downloaded from oracle.com and installed to `/opt/java8-oracle`
- Starting Android Studio via `env STUDIO_JDK=/opt/java8-oracle /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`