# How can I install Android Studio?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, application-development, android

I'm trying to install Android Studio but I found this error. Can someone help me?

If I write on terminal  `sudo apt-get install android-studio`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package android-studio
```

Comment: That is not how you install android-studio. Please follow this - http://askubuntu.com/questions/634082/android-studio-installation-on-14-04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to install Android-Studio without any serious problems is to first install Ubuntu-make: `sudo apt install umake`, and then run `umake android android-studio`. It should install flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

APT-GET can't see any program to install when it isn't in repositories base.

You've forgotten the first and second line ;-)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install android-studio
```

Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's the newest version of Ubuntu, which I believe is currently 20.04, or uses Snap as the software handler... Then it has to be;

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio
sudo apt-get update
sudo snap install android-studio --classic
```

Hope this assists anybody who ends up requiring my small bit of input.

Comment: Ubuntu supports both deb packages and snap packages. deb packages are generally handled by APT(frontend) or DPKG(backend). PPAs are for APT not Snaps. There's no PPA concept for snaps as of now.

Comment: Yes, but I literally have tried each and every one of the other methods of installation, and had problems until I tried my method. I'll post screenshots of my terminal if need be... I'm not proving anyone's input on the matter wrong, just adding to the fact that with this newest distro update, I've been experiencing some very odd methods, that I hadn't dealt with in previous versions is all.

Comment: Try removing PPA using `sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio` and retry the installation.

Comment: It wouldn't even install it without the repo though is what I'm getting at. Prior, it scanned through all of the repos I have already installed and said it didn't have the correct pubkey signature for installation. Any thoughts as to what that might be about..?

Comment: Were you using `snap` or `apt` before? If you were using `apt`, those errors make sense but in `snap`, they don't. Also, absence of PUB_KEY is another issue and is related to APT.

Comment: I kept alternating between the two to figure out what would work.