# Is there a tested walkthrough on how to set up android studio and Android SDK?

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu-for-android

I'd like to use android studio and Android SDK to learn how to create android apps on Ubuntu 15.10.

Does anyone know of a walkthrough that s/he has also tested with the above mentioned? If possible also other components too such as Java.

Cheers

Comment: Take a look at [`ubuntu-make`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make)

Comment: Here - http://askubuntu.com/questions/634082/android-studio-installation-on-14-04

Comment: @Cornelius cheers. I'll give it a go. Just heard of it too. Does it install all the required components too such as Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***UBUNTU 15.10 USERS....READ ALL THE COMMENTS TOO TO UNDERSTAND THE EASIEST WAY TO INSTAL UBUNTU MAKE ON YOUR COMPUTERS.***

#### First method: using Ubuntu Make

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ubuntu-make
umake android  //It will also download Open-JDK-7 if it's missing
```

#### Second method: install Oracle Java and Android Studio

Install Oracle Java 8 via repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Install Android Studio:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install android-studio
```

#### Additional: Creating desktop icon and uninstalling AS

Create a desktop file
.Create a new file androidstudio.desktop

```
nano ~/.local/share/applications/adndroidstudio.desktop
```

and add the lines below

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Android Studio
Exec="/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh" %f
Icon=/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.png
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=android-studio
```

Uninstall Android Studio :

```
umake android --remove
```

Visit also: [How to install Android Studio on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634082/android-studio-installation-on-14-04)

If you have any question, please free to ask

Comment: Is this for 15.10? I have just checked another post where it says 15.04 and above can do the installation simply by typing: sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make and then umake android since Ubuntu make is already in official repositories.

Comment: Yes, you're right,beacause from 15.04 version umake is in official repository of Ubuntu so you don't need to add repo before installing. Check this: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/12/ubuntu-developer-tools-center-renamed.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. Let me just ask one last thing.....when I type "ubuntu make" in the search box of the software center..why does it give me "ubuntu SDK" instead of "ubuntu make"? Ubuntu SDK and Ubuntu Make are the same, right?

Comment: Well, no... Ubuntu sdk helps you create apps for desktop and mobile devices with this system. Ubuntu make is only an feature which helps you to install IDEs with needed libraries as simply way as it can.