# Getting updates on Android Studio on Linux Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, android, android-studio

I have successfully installed Android studio on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS running as a guest in VMWare 10 on my windows 10. But when I check for updates it shows me some updates available and a message below which says :

```
Studio does not have write access to /home/aman/Downloads/android-studio. Please run it by a privileged user to update.
```

I am newbie in Linux environment, I know I have to give some read/write permission to studio but I don't know how.

P.S. I tried running it with the following command:

```
sudo ./studio.sh
```

it gives me an error saying :

```
tools.jar seems to be not in studio classpath. Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE
```

Comment: sudo sh /path.../studio.sh

Comment: @Mohammedaadhil No! Not with `sudo` not with `gksu` or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have Android Studio installed in your Download folder? Interesting... **o_O**

For your learning curve, correct the permissions:

```
sudo chown -R "$USER":"$USER" ~/Downloads
sudo chmod -R u+w ~/Downloads
```

After that, delete your installation **:P** and use [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/634085/367165) answer to install again.

Comment: I was just playing around with linux commands , so I accidently copied the studio folder in Downloads.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer

sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

Comment: Not sure what this will heelp.

Comment: "WebUpd8 team's PPA has been discontinued with effective from April 16, 2019" 

https://askubuntu.com/questions/634082/how-to-install-android-studio-on-ubuntu/634085#634085