# error in installing android studio using ubuntu make

Tags: 15.10, android

Ubuntu 15.10
When I tried to install android studio using ubuntu make it shows this error

```
$ umake android
Choose installation path: /home/prasanth/tools/android/android-studio
ERROR: We were expecting to find a license on the download page, we didn't.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issues gets solved when you provide [--accept-license  Accept license without prompting] option

```
umake android --accept-license
```

Comment: the wiki https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make   has bad info.  this answer works...