# Can not install 'openjdk-9-jdk' because it tries to overwrite file aready included in 'openjdk-9-jdk-headless'

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, openjdk

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial desktop, 64 bit, and wanted to install `openjdk-9-jdk` (Java 9 development kit). The version available from the `universe` repository is `9~b114-0ubuntu1`.

Running the installation command successfully installs the dependencies (see below, including package `openjdk-9-jdk-headless`), but fails to install the requested package itself because of a file provided by said dependency that is also present in the problematic package:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-9-jdk_9~b114-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/include/linux/jawt_md.h', which is also in package openjdk-9-jdk-headless:amd64 9~b114-0ubuntu1
```

Here's the full output:

```
$ sudo apt install openjdk-9-jdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java libice-dev libpthread-stubs0-dev libsm-dev libx11-dev libx11-doc libxau-dev libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev
  libxt-dev openjdk-9-jdk-headless openjdk-9-jre openjdk-9-jre-headless x11proto-core-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev
  xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
Suggested packages:
  libice-doc libsm-doc libxcb-doc libxt-doc openjdk-9-demo openjdk-9-source visualvm icedtea-8-plugin fonts-ipafont-gothic
  fonts-ipafont-mincho ttf-wqy-microhei | ttf-wqy-zenhei fonts-indic
The following NEW packages will be installed
  ca-certificates-java libice-dev libpthread-stubs0-dev libsm-dev libx11-dev libx11-doc libxau-dev libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev
  libxt-dev openjdk-9-jdk openjdk-9-jdk-headless openjdk-9-jre openjdk-9-jre-headless x11proto-core-dev x11proto-input-dev
  x11proto-kb-dev xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
0 to upgrade, 19 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 183 MB/187 MB of archives.
After this operation, 326 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ca-certificates-java all 20160321 [12,9 kB]
Get:2 http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 openjdk-9-jre-headless amd64 9~b114-0ubuntu1 [183 MB]
Get:3 http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 openjdk-9-jre amd64 9~b114-0ubuntu1 [51,5 kB]                       
Fetched 183 MB in 2min 21s (1.293 kB/s)                                                                                            
Selecting previously unselected package ca-certificates-java.
(Reading database ... 210101 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ca-certificates-java_20160321_all.deb ...
Unpacking ca-certificates-java (20160321) ...
Selecting previously unselected package openjdk-9-jre-headless:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../openjdk-9-jre-headless_9~b114-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openjdk-9-jre-headless:amd64 (9~b114-0ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package xorg-sgml-doctools.
Preparing to unpack .../xorg-sgml-doctools_1%3a1.11-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking xorg-sgml-doctools (1:1.11-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package x11proto-core-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../x11proto-core-dev_7.0.28-2ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking x11proto-core-dev (7.0.28-2ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libice-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libice-dev_2%3a1.0.9-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libice-dev:amd64 (2:1.0.9-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpthread-stubs0-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libpthread-stubs0-dev_0.3-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpthread-stubs0-dev:amd64 (0.3-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsm-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libsm-dev_2%3a1.2.2-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsm-dev:amd64 (2:1.2.2-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxau-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libxau-dev_1%3a1.0.8-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxau-dev:amd64 (1:1.0.8-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxdmcp-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libxdmcp-dev_1%3a1.1.2-1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxdmcp-dev:amd64 (1:1.1.2-1.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package x11proto-input-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../x11proto-input-dev_2.3.1-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking x11proto-input-dev (2.3.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package x11proto-kb-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../x11proto-kb-dev_1.0.7-0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking x11proto-kb-dev (1.0.7-0ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package xtrans-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../xtrans-dev_1.3.5-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking xtrans-dev (1.3.5-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxcb1-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libxcb1-dev_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxcb1-dev:amd64 (1.11.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libx11-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libx11-dev_2%3a1.6.3-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libx11-dev:amd64 (2:1.6.3-1ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libx11-doc.
Preparing to unpack .../libx11-doc_2%3a1.6.3-1ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libx11-doc (2:1.6.3-1ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxt-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libxt-dev_1%3a1.1.5-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxt-dev:amd64 (1:1.1.5-0ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package openjdk-9-jre:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../openjdk-9-jre_9~b114-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openjdk-9-jre:amd64 (9~b114-0ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package openjdk-9-jdk-headless:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../openjdk-9-jdk-headless_9~b114-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openjdk-9-jdk-headless:amd64 (9~b114-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../openjdk-9-jdk_9~b114-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openjdk-9-jdk:amd64 (9~b114-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-9-jdk_9~b114-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/include/linux/jawt_md.h', which is also in package openjdk-9-jdk-headless:amd64 9~b114-0ubuntu1
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20160104ubuntu1) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160415-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-9-jdk_9~b114-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So obviously this seems to be a bug and caused by incorrect packaging and not a fault on my side. There also are some related bug reports on Launchpad already, like e.g. [this report which seems to be the most important one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-9/+bug/1550950). I subscribed to that report, but there's no solution for Xenial yet.

Therefore my question here is *not about this packaging bug*, but **how to work around this and install `openjdk-9-jdk` anyway, ignoring the "trying to overwrite file" error?**

Comment: @NickWeinberg The `openjdk-9-jdk-headless` package is a required dependency of `openjdk-9-jdk`, therefore I have no chance to omit it.

Comment: Note that this is apparently due to openjdk9 being incorrectly packaged: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-9/+bug/1593191

Comment: @Stewbasic, do you know whether this is  going to be corrected?   Sounds a little ridiculous.

Comment: @AdrianM. Maybe ask on the bug (see the link in my comment)? In my case I didn't have any particular need for version 9 so I just downgraded to 8.

Comment: Just  a note for other people finding this thread. Version 9~b114-0ubuntu1 is old and not really useful at the moment. There are newer versions but they would have to be backported to xenial or installed manually: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=openjdk-9-jdk

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You can directly do `sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install openjdk-9-jdk`. If you are here, you already tried the installation without the `-o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite"` and you know which files will be silently overwritten.

Comment: The syntax is correct and there is no error message in the installation.  I am guessing that it does the same as your solution  : an installation that overwrites the file.

Answer (score 59):

I was able to solve the error myself by forcing the file override when installing the `.deb` package with `dpkg`.

Here's my workaround to install `openjdk-9-jdk` on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial (not tested on other releases) despite the error message about not overwriting a file provided by its dependency `openjdk-9-jdk-headless`:

1. Normally try to install the `openjdk-9-jdk` package, preferably using the package manager `apt`:

   ```
   sudo apt install openjdk-9-jdk
   ```

   This will install all of its dependencies and also download the binary package file. It should be stored at `/var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-9-jdk_9~b114-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb` now, but the file name's second half may differ in case you're having a different version.

   Please note that *we expect this single command to fail with the error message described in the question*. Ignore the error, we'll take care of that in the next steps.
2. The dependency packages were not fully configured yet because the installation of `openjdk-9-jdk` failed and got aborted. We have to do that manually now and simply trigger the configuration of all not yet configured packages:

   ```
   sudo dpkg --configure -a
   ```
3. Finally we install our `openjdk-9-jdk` package. Therefore we use the downloaded and cached binary package file we got in step 1. We have to add the `--force-overwrite` flag to make the package manager ignore our doubly provided file and quietly overwrite it.

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite '/var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-9-jdk_9~b114-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb'
   ```

   You may have to adapt the file name in case you're having a different version, or just use tab-completion to enter the file name: press <kbd>Tab</kbd> after having entered the file name up to the underscore (`...openjdk-9-jdk_`) and it should autocomplete the correct file name.

Comment: Not sure what exactly we're doing here but it worked for me. :-)

Comment: Awesome! thank you! If possible, I think it would be better if this answer was accepted because it is more detailed and step-by-step.

Comment: Seemed to work, but when i later needed to downgrade to 8 for some unrelated reason, i get errors at boot: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-9/+bug/1550950

Comment: I tested it: Yes, in this openjdk-9-jdk (openjdk-9-jdk_9~b114-0ubuntu1_amd64) the file "jawt_md.h" is identical as in this openjdk-9-jdk-headless (openjdk-9-jdk-headless_9~b114-0ubuntu1_amd64). Installed jdk-headless; copied "jawt_md.h" to a temp location; installed jdk; compared. Confirmed: OK installed contents after forcing overwrite. OK to try removing jdk-headless first - prompts you to remove both. CAUTION: removing jdk first DOES remove "jawt_md.h", which jdk-headless normally provides for building programs that process AWT graphics (albeit headless, that is, without displaying them).