# IcedTea and OpenJDK-8 packages errors after upgrading to 16.04

Tags: package-management, 16.04, dependencies

I just upgraded from 15.10 to 16.04 on my laptop and now I have errors with IcedTea and OpenJDK-8 related packages. There seems to be a problem with dependencies. Can someone tell me how to get rid of these errors? I have had no success so far.

Here is the output of `sudo apt-get upgrade` (sorry my system is in French but I think it is straightforward to understand):

```
[sudo] Mot de passe de brice : 
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Calcul de la mise à jour... Fait
0 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 0 non mis à jour.
4 partiellement installés ou enlevés.
Après cette opération, 0 o d'espace disque supplémentaires seront utilisés.
Souhaitez-vous continuer ? [O/n] O
Paramétrage de openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64 (8u91-b14-0ubuntu4~16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: erreur: le chemin alternatif /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/rmid n'existe pas
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64 (--configure) :
 le sous-processus script post-installation installé a retourné une erreur de sortie d'état 2
dpkg: des problèmes de dépendances empêchent la configuration de openjdk-8-jre:amd64 :
 openjdk-8-jre:amd64 dépend de openjdk-8-jre-headless (= 8u91-b14-0ubuntu4~16.04.1) ; cependant :
 Le paquet openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64 n'est pas encore configuré.

dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet openjdk-8-jre:amd64 (--configure) :
 problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré
dpkg: des problèmes de dépendances empêchent la configuration de icedtea-netx:amd64 :
 icedtea-netx:amd64 dépend de openjdk-8-jre ; cependant :
 Le paquet openjdk-8-jre:amd64 n'est pas encore configuré.

dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet icedtea-netx:amd64 (--configure) :
 problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré
dpkg: des problèmes de dépendances empêchent la configuration de icedtea-8-plugin:amd64 :
 icedtea-8-plugin:amd64 dépend de openjdk-8-jre ; cependant :
 Le paquet openjdk-8-jre:amd64 n'est pas encore configuré.
 icedtea-8-plugin:amd64 dépend de icedtea-netx (= 1.6.2-3ubuntAucun rapport « apport » n'a été créé car le message d'erreur indique une erreur consécutive à un échec précédent.
                Aucun rapport « apport » n'a été créé car le message d'erreur indique une erreur consécutive à un échec précédent.
                                                  Aucun rapport « apport » écrit car MaxReports a déjà été atteint
                                  u1) ; cependant :
 Le paquet icedtea-netx:amd64 n'est pas encore configuré.

dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet icedtea-8-plugin:amd64 (--configure) :
 problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64
 openjdk-8-jre:amd64
 icedtea-netx:amd64
 icedtea-8-plugin:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Possibly(?) related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/769467/can-not-install-openjdk-9-jdk-because-it-tries-to-overwrite-file-aready-includ

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! Thank you user xubu1957 on forum.ubuntu-fr.org: cf [here](https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?pid=21514846#p21514846)

In short:

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk-\*
sudo apt-get install openjdk-9-jre icedtea-8-plugin
```