# Git won't install, Ubuntu Studio

Tags: git, ubuntu-studio

I am a new user of Ubuntu Studio (and know nothing about coding, etc), and I am trying to install Linux Stopmotion, but it relies on Git, which won't install.

I get the following:

[image: Error on Terminal]

Basically, when trying to install Stopmotion it says that the program 'git' is not currently installed. So I go through the motions and try and install git using apt-get, by adding repositories, by doing most of the things on here other people have suggested, and it comes back saying that the following packages have unmet dependencies, or simply doesn't work.

The error is...

```
enchanting: Depends: java6-sdk

git: Depends: liberror-perl but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: git-man (>1:2.9.3) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: git-man (<1:2.9.3-.) but it is not going to be installed

E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

(I have tried the -f install and it doesn't work either.)

I don't know anything about coding, and I have never used linux before and am a lot over my head. Can someone please help me out? All I want to do is install Stopmotion.

Comment: Well, for starters, you forgot to run `apt-get -f install` with `sudo`. Try that and see if anything changes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run `apt-get -f install` with root rights. So execute:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

This fixes your broken dependencies.

Afterwards, do

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt-get check
sudo apt install git
```

The first command updates your package list, the second one upgrades your packages, the 3rd one will either output something like

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
```

to tell you your dependencies are fine now or it will tell you there are still problems. The last command will install git. You need git to do a git clone.

Then execute the git clone command again and it should work.

Comment: Ok, I tried apt-get -f install using sudo and I get the following message: while unpacking openjdk-9-jdk:amd64 (~b114-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ... dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-9-jdk_9~b114-0ubuntu_amd64.deb (--unpack): If I try continuing I still get the same errors as above when trying to install git, ie there are unmet dependencies.

Comment: Has already been solved. http://askubuntu.com/questions/769467/can-not-install-openjdk-9-jdk-because-it-tries-to-overwrite-file-aready-includ

Comment: Thank you! Using both solves it has worked and Stopmotion is successfully installed.

Comment: You're welcome. Please check the tick on the left to indicate to other users that this question has been solved.

Comment: @UTF-8, Is there a place to download git compiled binaries and just extract them? No installation or compilation. Just download it as you download ant other binary TAR.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`

**Add this:**

```
deb http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

**Update system:**

`apt-get update`

`apt-get upgrade`