# How to install android studio in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, android-studio

i need to install android studio in ubuntu system i followed some steps from documentation its installed but not running.

please give me stapes to install and also works.

[How to install Android Studio on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634082/how-to-install-android-studio-on-ubuntu)

Comment: We need more information other than "it's not working" please include specifics such as errors and whatnot, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install Oracle Java JDK 8:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Then download and unpack Android Studio archive from:

https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/2.2.0.12/android-studio-ide-145.3276617-linux.zip

Using terminal go to unpacked directory called `android-studio`, then `/bin` and run `./studio.sh` file