# Download apps from forbidden countries

Tags: 16.04, android-studio, gnu

Hello Ubuntu community.
I am a Syrian IT student who tries always to gain new skills but due to conflicts in Syria we are not allowed to download important programs such as Android Studio which is the main reason for me.
being forbidden is the opposite goal of GNU and Open Sources projects
so please if any one can give us a way to get access to download many important programs to us i would be very thankful..
**UPD**: to be specific I can access any website using Firefox Anonymox addon but the real problem is that i can't download any thing from these websites

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/634082/how-to-install-android-studio-on-ubuntu on how to install it. Now for the problem: you need to tell us who is blocking you from where. You need a proxy ...

Comment: actually Google is blocking Syrian devices from it's services.. as much as many other corporations

Comment: so don't use google. use another service to download (altavista? bing?)

Comment: the problem isn't about one service..
Google owns Android Studio.. etc

Comment: So the question is not about downloading android studio but about using it?

Comment: my friend some of Google's services is forbidden in Syria and many other corporations are doing the same like Oracle..
all what i'm asking for is a way to download these programs (Android studio + SDK , netbeans... etc)..

Comment: I think you can make a request to Google about it, maybe.

Comment: Try using a proxy/VPN that hides your real location.