# Error(s) while installing Android Studio using umake

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu-make

I'm trying to install Android Studio using `umake` with the command

```
sudo umake android android-studio
```

and I get the following errors:

```
Downloading and installing requirements
| ERROR: W:GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/olav-st/xUbuntu_16.04  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1BE1E8D7A2B5E9D5, W:The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/olav-st/xUbuntu_16.04  Release' is not signed., W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., W:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/texlive-backports/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file., W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., E:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/texlive-backports/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
    100% 
#########################################################################
| ERROR: Package requirements can't be met: W:GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/olav-st/xUbuntu_16.04  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1BE1E8D7A2B5E9D5, W:The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/olav-st/xUbuntu_16.04  Release' is not signed., W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., W:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/texlive-backports/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file., W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., E:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/texlive-backports/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How can I solve this issue? Searching on Google didn't help.

---

`umake` version: `16.11.1`
on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS 64-bit

---

**UPDATE (after dgonzalez answer)**

I followed your answer and now the error changes from a **missing key** to an **expired key**:

```
ERROR: W:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/texlive-backports/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file., W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., W:GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/olav-st/xUbuntu_16.04  Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1445355426, W:The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/olav-st/xUbuntu_16.04  Release' is not signed., W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., E:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/texlive-backports/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
100% |#########################################################################|
ERROR: Package requirements can't be met: W:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/texlive-backports/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file., W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., W:GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/olav-st/xUbuntu_16.04  Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1445355426, W:The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/olav-st/xUbuntu_16.04  Release' is not signed., W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., E:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/texlive-backports/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: As the error reads, *the repository is untrusted*. To install Android Studio follow this [guide](http://askubuntu.com/questions/634082/how-to-install-android-studio-on-ubuntu#634085) instead.

Comment: Do you have a particular reason for installing via **umake** over installing the binary package provided by **Google**?

Comment: why are you installing with `sudo umake android android-studio ` and not just `umake android android-studio `?

Comment: @L.D.James for the present, `umake`, and its cousin `sdkman`, are the prefererred way to install most developer tools.  There's a reason they exist.....

Comment: @Thufir I'll look into your suggestions in more detail in the future.  But at a glance, thought out the years of my installing applications I have always followed the **Readme** directions closely and very rarely have any problems.  The **Readme** is from the developers and distributors.  Following the distributer's provided steps should make it easier to get support if problems arise.  I don't recall seeing **umake** or **sdkman** in any of the instructions of any of the applications I have installed.   (continued)...

Comment: @L.D.James heh, fair point.  Probably less error prone.  Will have to agree to disagree over the merits to umake et. al.   :)     it's all good.

Comment: ... (continued)  I searched for the words **umake** and **sdkman** in my drive of hundreds of installs from **git**.  The make search: **`egrep -rl "\bmake\b" | wc -l`** returns `2187`.  **umake** and **sdkman** both return `0`.  I don't now the reason you suggest for using it since you didn't mention the reason.  But I have found that following the provided steps by the developers makes it easier for them to see where you are going wrong if you experience an issue.

Comment: the original poster, the question, is tagged `umake`.  I highly recomend it, yes, it has a very nice man page.   But it's that the question is within the context of umake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Seems you have a missing GPG key for the required package(s).

You are seeing this issue because `apt` cannot find a matching GPG key for the required package(s) installed on your system *(maybe `ubuntu-make` ppa added correctly, but an error occurred when adding signing key¿?)*.

As a personal advice, i would consider always first using the default software channels, and *only add a ppa* if there is any **special requirement(s)** which default software doesn't cover.

#### Adding/retrieving GPG key(s) from *keyserver.ubuntu.com*

You can check if that certain GPG key exist in *keyserver.ubuntu.com* and automatically add it to your system. To do this simply run this on your terminal:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 1BE1E8D7A2B5E9D5
```

If the key exists, it will be added to your system and you'll be able to install `ubuntu-make` with `sudo apt install ubuntu-make`.

#### Reverting your system *(removing the ppa)*

If no packages were installed/changed, you can simply remove the ppa *(repo)* file and entry from apt sources, running the following command on your terminal:

`sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-ubuntu-make-xenial.list*`

However I'll always suggest best using `ppa-purge` *(you can install it with `sudo apt install ppa-purge`)*, which in addition to remove the sources entry, it also removes the added keys and does all other *genuflections*, like reverting packages to their equivalent on the main repos *(if any were installed)*.

Run this on your terminal to remove and purge *ubuntu-make ppa* using `ppa-purge`:

`sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make`

*Tip: You can use bash autocompletion with <kbd>Tab</kbd> to fill ppa name.*

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for helping. The error changes from a missing key to an expired key (more details in the original question).

Comment: @BlackBrain Maybe they GPG key has expired and has to be updated _(by ppa maintainer(s))_. I also recommend to can use the default `ubuntu-make` package which is available directly on Ubuntu 16.04+ _(ubuntu-make version 16.05)_, answer updated.