# How to download images from Android to Ubuntu-PC

Tags: files, android

I would like to transfer the images I took with my android phone (version 7.1.2) to my Ubuntu PC.

How does this work?

It would be nice to have a solution which requires no cable (USB).

Answer (score 2):

You can either connect your phone via USB and copy and paste from the file manager or alternativly, if both of your devices are connected to the same network, you can install airdroid on android to send your images remotely and login to airdroid through your web browser.

[AirDroid](https://www.airdroid.com/en/get.html)

If you need any help or come across any errors, feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a lot of files (hundreds) need to be transferred **I prefer USB cable** over any other solution simply because of speed.

If only a single or very few fotos need to be sent I often choose a simple **e-mail** approach where I attach those photos to an email I then send to myself. This can be done from anywhere and from any network.

If at home you can of course also use your local network to transfer files. One easy approach would be to copy files to a (Samba) **network share** on the Ubuntu PC. This requires Android software which enables network access (e.g. a [file manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asus.filemanager&hl=de)) to copy your files to a network share.

But there are plenty of other solutions. Take e.g. a backup or storage in the Google (or any other!) **cloud storage** that would of course also be accessible from Ubuntu, choose a custom **backup software**, or - if your PC has a working adapter - use **Bluetooth** for file transfer.

It really depends on your personal preferences, setup, experience...

Answer (score 1):

If you're handy with the command line, another option is using the android debug bridge over tcp.

Once you have remote cli control of your device from your desktop you could navigate to your photos dir and pull to your desktop. Not super convenient, but this is how I push music files to to my android phone in a pinch.

To setup follow this ubuntu guide for adb:
[How to install Android Studio on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634082/how-to-install-android-studio-on-ubuntu)

And then make sure you enable Settings > Developer Options > "enable" ADB over network.

To get developer options if you don't already have them enabled:

> If using stock Android, go to Settings > About phone > Build number. On a Samsung Galaxy device, go to >Settings > About device > Build number. ...
>   Tap Build number seven times. ...
>   Go back to Settings, where you'll find a Developer options entry in the menu.

Once installed:
On your terminal simply run
`adb connect your_devices_ip_address`
to connect

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question: I use [Nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com/) now.

Either run it on you own server or pay for a hosted service.

It is worth the effort/money.

Answer (score 0):

If your phone and computer are on the same network you may try [KDE Connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kde.kdeconnect_tp&hl=en).