# Integrate Android Studio with Unity

Tags: unity, android-studio, hud, globalmenu

is there a way to properly integrate Android Studio with Unity Desktop Environment?

I'm not looking for help about [how to install android studio on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634082/how-to-install-android-studio-on-ubuntu), neither to add a desktop entry in order to have it on the launcher. I've already installed it [following the Android instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html) and I have it up and working.

What I'm missing though, it's an actual integration with the [features of the Unity DE](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/04/best-unity-desktop-features): menu bar shown inside the Window's title bar (global menu), commands easily accessible through Alt key (HUD support) and, hopefully, Progress status & Badges in the unity launcher.

I haven't myself tried to use [Ubuntu Make](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make) to install android studio and see if it results in better results, maybe someone who has can confirm it?