# A problem installing Eclipse with Java 9 to Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse

I have Xubuntu 17.10. I tried to install Eclipse via apt-get. When I tried to run it, I got an error

```
An error has occurred. See the log file
/home/jaakko/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration/1510564798671.log.
```

The log file is the following:

```
!SESSION 2017-11-13 11:19:57.077 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=debbuild
java.version=9.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 4 0 2017-11-13 11:20:00.209
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.301.dist [1]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: CDC-1.1/Foundation-1.1,J2SE-1.4
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1332)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1316)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-11-13 11:20:00.222
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.301.dist.jar was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-11-13 11:20:00.256
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-11-13 11:20:00.256
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.301.dist.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 2 0 2017-11-13 11:20:00.256
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.1))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4)))".

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-11-13 11:20:00.268
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-11-13 11:20:00.268
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.301.dist [1] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 2 0 2017-11-13 11:20:00.268
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.1))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4)))".

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-11-13 11:20:00.281
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

I found this problem occurs if I use Java 9 but not if I use Java 8.

How can I install Eclipse to my computer to run Java 9?

Comment: Make sure JDK is installed on your system before installing eclipse.

Comment: I have installed Java: `java version "9.0.1"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)` and `default-jdk 2:1.8-59ubuntu1`

Comment: check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24669940/java-8-missing-required-capability-require-capability-osgi-ee-filter-osg)

Comment: What release of Eclipse? You need the Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a) release for Java 9.

Comment: It looks like I have 3.8.1.

Comment: try adding `--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM` in eclispe.ini file and let us know if it works.

Comment: @g_p I have that line on eclipse.ini. The problem is still there.

Comment: I had same issue with Eclipse neon and  openjdk 9,this one worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Ubuntu 18.04 and later

The Eclipse snap package from the default Ubuntu repositories is perfect for Java programming because it is bundled with a Java development environment. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install eclipse --classic
```

This command will install the latest Photon Release 4.8 version of Eclipse IDE for Java Developers which was updated 8 days ago. Eclipse changed its codename policy so that Eclipse releases from September 2018 and onward are named after the year and month of the release date, for example Eclipse 2020-06. This naming scheme also applies to the eclipse snap package.

Eclipse Photon JDT supports Java 9 completely:

- The Eclipse compiler for Java (ECJ) implements all the new Java 9 language enhancements.
- Updated significant features to support Java Modules, such as compiler, search and many editor features.

**Note:**
In order to add a new Java version to Eclipse in 18.04 and later, for example openjdk-11-jdk, follow the instructions listed above in steps 1-9, only replace the string `java-9-openjdk` with the java version that you want to add to *Installed JREs*.

---

#### Ubuntu 17.10

I have installed Eclipse Oxygen (the latest version of Eclipse) and openjdk-9-jdk and Eclipse is working with openjdk-9-jdk in this version. If you want to keep openjdk-8-jdk as the default Java version to use in your new Eclipse Oxygen, you can open Eclipse and add openjdk-9-jdk from inside Eclipse as follows.

1. Select *Window* -> *Preferences*
2. In the pane on the right side of the Preferences window, click the black triangle to the left of *Java* to unfold it.
3. Double-click *Installed JREs*.
4. Click the **Add** on the left side of the preferences window to add a new JRE.
5. Select *Standard VM* and click **Next**.
6. In the JRE Home: field type `/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64` (or i386 instead of amd64 for 32-bit Eclipse)
7. In the JRE Name: field type `java-9-openjdk-amd64` (or i386 instead of amd64 for 32-bit Eclipse)
8. Click the **Apply** button.
9. Now in *Installed JREs* in Step 3. you can click the checkbox to the left of a JRE in the list of installed JREs to select it as the default and click the **Apply** button to apply the change in the default Installed JRE.

The same instructions do not work for the default version of Eclipse in Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to install the `openjdk-8-jre`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
   ```
2. Next switch to the jre-8 version:

   ```
   $ sudo update-alternatives --config java
   There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

   Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status

   * 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java       1091      auto mode
     1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
     2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java       1091      manual mode
   ```
3. check java version:

   ```
   $ java -version
   openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-0ubuntu0.17.10.2-b12)
   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
   ```
4. start eclipse

Comment: this one worked for me