# Installing Eclipse Oxygen On Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, launcher, eclipse

I downloaded Eclipse Oxygen from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ and went through the installation process, but after installing when I click "eclipse" at `/home/rizwan/eclipse/java-oxygen/eclipse`, it should open IDE but I am not able to open the IDE it shows:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
-jar /home/rizwan/eclipse/java-oxygen/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /home/rizwan/eclipse/java-oxygen/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/rizwan/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.551.v20171108-1834/eclipse_1630.so
-startup /home/rizwan/eclipse/java-oxygen/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata cc001d
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
-jar /home/rizwan/eclipse/java-oxygen/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A problem installing Eclipse with Java 9 to Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975959/a-problem-installing-eclipse-with-java-9-to-ubuntu) You need to open Eclipse Oxygen with Java 8 as the default Java version, and then add Java 9 to Eclipse from the Eclipse Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Review `eclipse.ini`. Remove duplicate entries and remove `--add-modules` lines. After such cleanup eclipse started for me on openjdk9. Not sure if I will face some other issues, will report back.

EDIT: After checking `java -help` it turns out that there is an option `-addmods` which was in an early access of Java 9. Now it's called `--add-modules`. Seems like the jdk in ubuntu repo is quite old (explains why it's called 9-internal)

EDIT2: As suspected: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=openjdk-9-jdk

- xenial: 9~b114-0ubuntu1: amd64 i386
- zesty: 9~b161-1: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
- artful: 9~b181-4: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
- bionic: 9.0.1+11-1: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x