# Unistalling Android studio compeletly

Tags: android, android-studio

i recently installed Android Studio using this method "[How to install Android Studio on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634082/how-to-install-android-studio-on-ubuntu)"

something wrong happened during the installation when i open the app it gave me an error loading the virtual phone inside the application i want to fully remove android studio and REinstall it again , I tried deleting the /android-studio folder along with the hidden /.android

I have tried

sudo apt-get remove android-studio

it says failed to locate the package .

i have tried all the methods here , i don't know maybe i did something wrong or i just jumped a step i don't know ! i'm trying to learn Linux but oh my god   unstoppable problems

Comment: How *exactly* did you install Android Studio? The linked question has 14 different answers. You can link directly to answers via the “share” link below them.

Answer (score 1):

there is nothing special about installing Android Studio in Ubuntu, installing Android Studio is straight forward.

first, you need JRE installed, you can install JRE by following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

and then just download [zip](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) file of Android Studio and then extract it where ever you wanted to install it.

and then run this command while staying inside extracted folder:

```
$ ./bin/studio.sh
```

## **To uninstall**, just delete installation folder and .android folder OR you can look at this long answer: [Install and Uninstall with Screenshot and Full Details](https://askubuntu.com/a/988441/780037)

```
$ sudo rm .android
```

It is just simple.

Thanks.

Comment: +1 I forgot to remove the .android directories..