# Android Studio 3 download problem

Tags: software-installation, 17.10, android-studio

Android Studio keeps repeating the same link at the rate of 10 lines/ second, and the download doesn't progress even after hours. I've tried switching from Linux to Windows, but the same problem occurs.

[image: Download Link Keeps Repeating Itself]

Comment: I have experienced the **exact same error** and I solved it by [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634082/how-to-install-android-studio-on-ubuntu/988441#988441) for which I awarded a 100 point bounty to Aleksandr Medvedev, but you have to follow the steps **exactly** or else you will continue to get the same error. It's clear that you have not followed these steps exactly because Ubuntu 17.04 is an EOL (End Of Life) release and the software in 17.04 no longer receives updates.

Comment: Upgraded To Version 17.10. Followed The Exact Same Steps Twice! Still The Same Problem.

Comment: I may have figured out what you did wrong by looking at your screenshot. It says in the instructions to use `sudo` because su isn't the same user that you need to be when installing Android Studio. Just repeat the instructions and use `sudo` every time instead of `su` or `sudo -i` and maybe it will work. Especially don't use `sudo -i` if you don't want to keep getting the same error.

Comment: Thanks. It Worked! The Link Kept Repeating But I Guess It Was All About Patience. Took 5 6 Hours To Download.

Comment: The next step is to find a simple demo Android program (Android hello world example in Android Studio) and try to run it.