# is it possible to use android SDK's windows version on linux?

Tags: android, android-sdk

I have android SDK on windows and now i need SDK in linux.Is it possible to download SDK for linux and then move SDK's tools and other folders from windows to linux instead of downloading it again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly recommend [installing Android SDK again](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634082/how-to-install-android-studio-on-ubuntu) in Ubuntu. At the cost of using some additional disk space, it will save you a lot of time and also give better stability and performance. This also might even result in saving disk space if you find that Android SDK works so much better in either Windows or Ubuntu that you could uninstall Android SDK in the other OS in order to save disk space. Saving disk space is a legitimate concern especially if you are installing Android SDK on an SSD where disk space is at a premium in order to get better performance from the application.