# Android Studio hardware accelerated emulator will not launch in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, virtualization, android-studio

I have a problem with my ASUS [G53jw](https://www.asus.com/ROG-Republic-Of-Gamers/ROG-G53Jw/specifications/) PC. Its [chipset](https://ark.intel.com/products/43183/Mobile-Intel-HM55-Express-Chipset) and [CPU](https://ark.intel.com/products/43544/Intel-Core-i5-540M-Processor-3M-Cache-2_53-GHz) are rated to support virtualisation, which is enabled in the BIOS/Setup. To confirm, I ran `egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo` which returns a value of four (4)  which suggests virtualisation should work.

However, hardware accelerated Android emulation fails to launch.

Is the use of the nouveau video driver instead of an Nvidia driver the source of the failure? If not, how may I effectively troubleshoot this?

**UPDATE 2**
After installing official Nvidia drivers the Android emulation runs just fine :) Thanks to N0rbert for pointing out my typo!
Solved!

Comment: First of all you have typo in `egrep` command (you need logical or here "|", not backslash "\"). It should be `egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo`. Run it and add result to the question.

Comment: Thanks! The weird result was caused by my typo indeed.

Comment: To mark question as solved I posted my comment as answer. Other option was to delete the question.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912). You should ask about your actual problem, not what you think the solution is (as we've seen it isn't).

Comment: @Joel Sahlin, we need some specific info here. Please click on the grey edit link above at left and add it into the question.  Did you install Android Studio through Wine, Openbox, kvm, or some other virtual OS; or, did you install it directly into the Ubuntu system? Please advise exactly how you did it, for there are four, count them, 4 methods known at https://askubuntu.com/questions/634082/how-to-install-android-studio-on-ubuntu for installation of Android Studio directly into Ubuntu, plus the virtual alternatives.

Comment: I have android studio directly installed on ubuntu. No virtualization. The problem was emulating android on my ubuntu system and the typo made me think that I had a real problem. I am so happy that it was just a typo. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have typo in `egrep` command:
you need logical OR here "`|`", not backslash "`\`".

It should be `egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo`.

Reading your update we can conclude that it was a typo.

---

Other way to check is to use `kvm-ok` (installable from `cpu-checker` package).

On system with enabled virtualization its output is as follows:

```
$ kvm-ok
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used
```

---

If you have problems with VirtualBox - ensure that you have set correct **Settings** for virtual machine: open **System**, select **Acceleration** tab and check that you have correct settings:

- **Paravirtualization Interface**: *Default*
- **Hardware Virtualization**: ☑ *Enable VT-x/AMD-v*, ☑ *Enable Nested Paging*

  [image: VirtualBox - System - Acceleration]

This will result in blue V ([image: V on CPU]) on CPU icon in status bar of VirtualBox machine window (see yellow hint below for details - machine uses KVM) :

[image: VirtualBox status bar]

Comment: Yes but I still have problems with virtualization so it is not completely solved yet.

Comment: What kind of problems do you have?

Comment: Thank you for your help! :) The problem is fixed now. The typo made me think that I had a different problem then I actually had. All I needed in the end was the official graphics drivers. Again thanks for pointing out my typo! :)