# Cannot run VirtualBox VMs on Core 2 CPU. System requirements?

Tags: virtualbox, cpu

I have tried running VirtualBox 5 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on three machines with Core 2 CPUs (specifically, [E7300](https://ark.intel.com/products/36463/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E7300-3M-Cache-2_66-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB), [L7500](https://ark.intel.com/products/29757/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-L7500-4M-Cache-1_60-GHz-800-MHz-FSB) and [L9400](https://ark.intel.com/products/36689/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-SL9400-6M-Cache-1_86-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB)). On all three machines I have attached Ubuntu 16.04 LTS ISO as a boot device to install Ubuntu as a host OS. On all three machines this resulted in VirtualBox crashing in the same way: it displays a dialog box saying

> **Guru Meditation**
>
> A critical error has occurred while running the
> virtual machine and machine execution has been stopped.
>
> [...]
>
> Press OK
> if you want to power off the machine of press Ignore if you want to
> leave it as for debugging. Please note that debugging requires special
> knowledge and tools, so it is recommended to press OK now.

at which point the whole graphical desktop hangs and I have to switch to console and kill VirtualBox via `htop`.

I suspect that these systems do not pass some unspecified system requirements. If so, what are they, exactly? I thought a CPU with VT-x would suffice, at least. While E7300 doesn't have VT-x, L7500 and L9400 do.

Here's the [logs](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Vw3x4ww9f3/). Here's the screenshot (it's pitch black):
[image]

VirtualBox site moderator [suggests](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=88974#p426564) this is a question relevant to Ubuntu, not VirtualBox because this version of VirtualBox is provided by Ubuntu.

Comment: It clearly written that E7300 does not have VT-x. But two other CPUs have VT-x. Anyway you should have VT-x enabled in the BIOS. Then can try to run `kvm-ok` command on them. The result will show existence of hardware virtualisation. I have tested `kvm` on Atoms and Celerons without VT-x. It will work, but very slow. You can try to setup VirtualBox to use software acceleration (see this answer for [corresponding screenshots](https://askubuntu.com/a/1057566/66509)). Also you can read [VirtualBox docs - sec. 3.5.3 and 10.3](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#idm1426).

Comment: Other posibility that anti-meltdown/anti-spectre remediations break Ubuntu-packaged VirtualBox for your Intel processors. Did you tried to use VirtualBox from Oracle? I mean [this instructions](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads).

Comment: Another possibility is a corrupted ISO. Did you by any chance [check the hash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503776/md5-hash-for-ubuntu-iso-14-04-through-18-04/503788)

Comment: Did you dual-boot the vm? I tryed to dual-boot my vm and it now shows that pop-up.