# Do I need to install Eclipse to be able to develop applications with Cordova and Phonegap?

Tags: application-development, eclipse

I have managed to install the Android SDK thanks to the response of the user @Kin. I only have one question, is it necessary to install eclipse to develop with cordova and Phonegap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's recommended to install Android Studio at [Android Platform Guide - Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html).

> #### Installing the Requirements
>
> - Java Development Kit (JDK)
>
>   Install Java Development Kit (JDK) 8. JDK 8 is installed automatically by Android Studio.
> - Gradle
>
>   As of Cordova-Android 6.4.0, Gradle is now required to be installed to build Android. Manual
>     installation of Gradle is not required because Gradle comes bundled with Android Studio.
> - Android SDK
>
>   Install [Android Studio](https://askubuntu.com/q/634082/). It's not necessary to install Eclipse too because Android SDK is installed by Android Studio.
>
>   System Requirements for Android Studio
>
>   - 3 GB RAM minimum, 8 GB RAM recommended; plus 1 GB for the Android Emulator
>   - 2 GB of available disk space minimum, 4 GB recommended
> - Adding SDK Packages
>
>   After installing the Android SDK, you must also install the packages for whatever API level you wish to target. It is recommended
>     that you install the highest SDK version that your version of
>     cordova-android supports (see [Requirements and
>     Support](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#requirements-and-support)).

Comment: Gradle is an Android Studio component. Manual installation of Gradle is not required because Gradle comes bundled with Android Studio.

Comment: I installed mine by following the instructions in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/634082/how-to-install-android-studio-on-ubuntu/988441#988441 which works, but you must follow the instructions to the letter and don't try to customize the defaults in the installation wizard. Eclipse apt package didn't work for me in 18.04, but the more recent Eclipse snap package works. It's the latest version of Eclipse. You don't need Eclipse for Android anymore.

Comment: My studiosh is in `/opt/google/android-studio/bin/studio.sh` and has executable file permissions. Running it from the terminal with `sh /opt/google/android-studio/bin/studio.sh` starts Android Studio. When AS starts it shows you the AS splash screen. Look in the lower right corner, there's a Configure dropdown menu accessed by clicking the downward pointing black triangle. Click the black triangle and from the dropdown menu select *Create Desktop Entry* to create an Android Studio icon for starting AS by clicking its green icon in the Dash.

Comment: Thanks for the support @karel. I followed the steps of the installation and I have several errors. I believe that I must accept his answer for good and ask another question to try to solve the errors. What do you think about this? I want to do things as well as possible and that my questions can help others. Thank you.

Comment: I agree that clicking the checkmark beside the answer to mark it as accepted and asking a new question would prevent this question from being dragged into being too broad. Asking multiple questions in the same question is generally discouraged on all Stack Exchange network sites. It was a fun question to answer that helped me to update an answer to another Android Studio question that I posted a few months ago.

Comment: Hello @karel, I asked the question and I have no answer, maybe you have some idea of how to correct my problem or where I can find a solution. Thank you https://askubuntu.com/questions/1119448/how-to-fix-android-studio-installation-and-gradle-errors