# How to open Android Studio on i3

Tags: android-studio, i3-wm

`i3` is turning out not to be as simple as the instructions claim. For example the instructions claim I can open an application with partial name. So I tried opening the Chrome browser by typing `chrome` and that didn't work; I had to type `google-chrome` for it to work. Now I am trying to open **Android Studio** but nothing I try works so far. I have tried typing `studio`, `android-studio`, `jetbrains-studio` -- nothing.

Does anyone know a simple way to get opening applications to work? I mean, opening applications is among the most relevant tasks and it's proving too difficult.

Comment: How is it related to Ubuntu?

Comment: This is all happening in Ubuntu

Comment: How did you installed Android Studio?

Comment: See this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/634082/how-to-install-android-studio-on-ubuntu . Make sure the location of the adroid studio executable (studio.sh in the answer) is added to the PATH variable, if it's not dmenu ( the launcher in i3) won't "look" in the right place for it. To do this, add to .bashrc or .profile in your home folder: `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/directory/of/executable`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I open `vim ~/.profile` and as the last line I added: `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/more_path/android.sh`. Then I restarted i3 and it still doesn't work if I search for `android` in dmenu. And yes I get the location of android studion by doing `whereis android`

Comment: Does `./android.sh` in the terminal in the directory /usr/more_path/ work? Is android.sh executable? (If not `(sudo) chmod +x android.sh`) And as Kulfy asked, how did you install Android Studio Exactly?

Comment: The following starts android studio in the terminal: `$ /opt/android-studio-3.0/bin/studio.sh` but no matter what I do I cannot get it to start from dmenu. I cannot settle for the terminal avenue because then I would always need to have a terminal window open just so I can have Android Studio running.

Comment: also, I installed from terminal. My Android Studio works fine. I am just now switching from Cinnamon to i3 and that's the whole of my issue: how do I open studio through dmenu?

Comment: Ok, what is the output of `echo $PATH` and which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Furtermore, you shouldn't add an executable to PATH but the path to the directory the executable is in. So e.g. add /opt/android-studio-3.0/bin/ to PATH, without studio.sh.

Comment: `echo $PATH` reveals that `/opt/android-studio-3.0/bin/studio.sh` is part of the path. Re "you shouldn't add an executable to PATH", are you saying my path should simply have `/opt/android-studio-3.0/bin/` and that should do it?

Comment: Yes to your last question.

Comment: So it turns out the path gets added only when I add it to `.bashrc`. After I add it I restart and then verify that `echo $PATH` returns properly. But then I still cannot open studio from the dmenu.

Comment: Well, did some research. Installed Ubuntu18.04 in a vm, chose the budgie desktop and installed android studio via the steps in the link I shared earlier. Android Studio works nicely. After having done this I installed i3. I added the directory I installed android studio in to PATH in /home/me/.profile, rebooted the system, chose i3 in the dm, typed studio.sh in dmenu, dmenu found it immediately, I hit enter and Android Studio started as it should. I cannot reproduce your issue. I have no solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by adding the following line to my `.bashrc`

`export PATH="/usr/local/android-studio/bin:$PATH"`

NOTE

- `/usr/local/android-studio/bin` is the directory that has `studio.sh` on my machine. I followed [the official install instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/install#linux). The directory may be different for you.
- For some reason this wouldn't work when I had put $PATH at the beginning, so if it's not working for you then try putting $PATH at the end of the string like I did here.
- Remeber to reboot