# Which Java package to install (and how) to develop web and android apps?

Tags: java, android, jdk

I would like to install java to learn to program in java and develop web and android apps. I'm running on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (which doesn't come with java pre-installed). I have seen that there a number of possibilities: OpenJDK, Apache JDK, and each with different versions of Java.

Which one would you recommend to install given my specifications, and which commands do I need to issue to the terminal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Android Studio on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634082/how-to-install-android-studio-on-ubuntu) If you are missing a package Android Studio will often prompt you to install it, including sometimes the required package version.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I am in the process of learning java, so I didn't want to install android studio just yet. Nevertheless, I can follow the part on installing java for now. Just one thing, the answer says to install java 8 ```sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer``` right? However I found on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history that the latest lts version is Java 11. Therefore, should I install this instead: ```sudo apt-get install oracle-java11-installer``` ?

Comment: Android Studio does not support Java 11, only Java 8, however you can install openjdk-8-jdk with `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk` instead of Oracle Java 8. For a Java IDE I recommend Apache NetBeans 10. To install it type `sudo snap install --classic netbeans`.

Comment: Ok, thank you for this info. And which one would you recommend between OpenJDK and OracleJDK? Are there major differences?

Comment: Oracle packages things together in their Java package that Ubuntu packages separately as separate packages.

Comment: I would like to give detailed installation procedure for **Oracle Java JDK-11** for Ubuntu 18.04, but I don't see a way to post answer.

Comment: Hi Marmayogi, this is because it was marked as a duplicate. So it is not possible anymore to answer the question...