# Install Android Studio using a terminal in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, android-studio

I've downloaded the tar file from Android Studio's official site. Now I want to install it using a terminal in the Ubuntu operating system. JDK is already installed and configured.

What are the steps to install Android Studio using a terminal?

Comment: android-studio is available as snap package. Have you tried `sudo snap install android-studio` ?

Comment: I just tried it after years since the last time I used it, and it appears it does not need any installation still. You will find `studio.sh` in the `bin` directory, once you've opened the tarball (by issuing `tar xzf <android-studio-tarball-file-name>`). If this is not sufficient, please provide further information of what exactly are you looking to install.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Android Studio on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634082/how-to-install-android-studio-on-ubuntu)

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** To make your issue easier to resolve, can you please edit your question to include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're using? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

by terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maarten-fonville/android-studio
sudo apt update
sudo apt install android-studio -y
```

you can use local package installer like as Gdebi

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question.After downloading android studio tar file from their official site, just go to downloaded directory extract the tar file and open terminal in that directory and run below command to move android studio to desired location.

```
sudo mv android-studio /opt
```

Now in home directory, open .bashrc file and add below lines on bottom of this file to set up environment variables.(if you dont see the .bashrc file in home directory then just check Show Hidded Files)

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Android/Sdk/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
```

Android studio is installed, now you can use this command to launch it

```
/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
```

Note: I have already installed and configured jdk. if you want to upgrade android studio to latest then first uninstall outdated android studio then perform all above instructions.