# Invalid operation?? after i type sudo apt-get cpufrequtils

Tags: command-line

For so many commands which i type are correct even then i have errors like unable to locate package or sometimes it gives "invalid operation" . This error really kills me, how can i fix this?

Comment: Note: instead of `apt-get` you can use `apt`.  It does the same things in a more beginner friendly way plus it colorize output etc.

Comment: @Bakuriu make it an answer with some examples or I will add it into mine and profit from it ;-)

Answer (score 15):

This

```
sudo apt-get cpufrequtils
```

is missing a mandatory option. To install or remove use...

```
sudo apt-get install cpufrequtils
sudo apt-get remove cpufrequtils
```

Comment: Rinzwind's answer is correct but just to add some help if you are not sure you are choosing the correct package name you can look it up with 'apt-cache search [package-name]'. Even with a partial package name this will return a list of similar packages.

Comment: hahaha, I feel like an idiot.. i forgot the "install" option...

Answer (score 1):

An more morecent alternative to `apt-get` is the `apt` command (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445384/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-and-apt-get) for a discussion about their differences).

Maybe using `apt` you more easily realize that installing isn't the only thing that these tool do. And as such you first have to tell them the operation you want to perform:

```
sudo apt install cpufrequtils
```

Without the `install` the command wouldn't know whether you want to install or uninstall that package or if you simply want to search for it.

The name `apt-get` *may* sound like it only "gets"("install") the programs, but this isn't true.

---

You should prefer `apt` for interactive use as it provides a cleaner interface and colorized human friendly output. Use `apt-get` or `apt-cache` for scripts.