# Xubuntu software updater doesn't update

Tags: xubuntu, update-manager

For a long time, software updater does not update. When it notifies there are available updates, I run install and it starts; however, after 1-2 seconds it suddenly disappear and does not update obviously. Before it disappears, at the bottom of the progress window, it says something like 'Waiting for authentication' (but I am not sure because it disappears very very fast. Though I run it again and again, I couldn't read it precisely)

I run these commands from the terminal to update manually:

```
sudo apt-get install update
sudo apt-get install upgrade
```

After that, some of the updates(e.g chromium etc.) has been installed but there are others that are not updated:

[image: Here is the left ones]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to do something the commands are not built to do!
The correct way to update is :

```
Sudo apt-get update
```

This update the cash. The new way is:

```
Sudo apt update
```

Likewise with the actual upgrade:

```
Sudo apt-get upgrade  /  sudo apt upgrade
```

Do see the manual for the install options, You have installed the Update and the Upgrade programs, they come standard with any Ubuntu flavor, and most other Debians!

Comment: Have you read this : http://askubuntu.com/questions/445384/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-and-apt-get.? Both `apt` and `apt-get` should work. Actually `apt-get` gives you more options than `apt`.

Comment: It does the job! Though, in the link above it says they are same, apt has upgrade flag --with-new-pckgs. I think this is why it worked. However, why the Software Updater couldn't do that and how to fix it are still a mystery for me!