# Is 'apt-get' deprecated?

Tags: command-line, apt, 16.04, bash

Lately, I've seen many people use

```
sudo apt
```

instead of

```
sudo apt-get
```

Also, Ubuntu keeps telling me to install things by `sudo apt`

```
The program 'foo' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install foo
```

(remember, foo is placeholder, not an app)

So, after this popularity in the community about using `apt` instead of `apt-get`, I'm starting to think that apt-get is deprecated and can no longer be used in my bash programs.

In my bash programs,

- do I have to replace all `apt-get` commands with `apt`?
- is `apt-get` dangerous?
- will my programs still work?

Comment: See this related post:  http://askubuntu.com/q/445384/295286

Comment: Apt is prettier than apt-get

Comment: The reason why some users (such as myself) use `apt` is because it's shorter than `apt-get`. Less keystrokes, less time spent. I use `apt-get` for things like `check` though.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`apt-get` is lower level and backwards compatible. `apt` is better for end-users and doesn't require or contain some extra features in that are present in `apt-get`.

Both are perfectly fine. `apt-get` is not deprecated, but your 15.10 installation is :)

Edit: From the man page of apt(8)

> The apt command is meant to be pleasant for end users and does not need
>          to be backward compatible like apt-get(8).

Edit2: `apt` was designed to fix some of the fundamental dependency flaws in `apt-get`. As it is a wrapper, `apt` is therefore higher level, and also loses some backward compatibility and scripting features.

Comment: What features aren't in apt-get not in apt? And how apt is better for end user?

Comment: Again, apt-get is not lower level than apt. This is a misleading information. apt is on same level as apt-get and apt is nothing but a wrapper around apt-get and apt-cache

Comment: @Anwar: There are differences. One example: `apt upgrade` ≠ `apt-get upgrade`, since the former installs new packages, while the latter does not.

Comment: @Anwar If `apt` is a wrapper arount `apt-get` then it's definitely higher-level.

Comment: @Anwar That's actually the definition of being "higher level" or "lower level".  apt is higher level *because* it wraps apt-get.  A sort of test is that if your apt got corrupted, apt-get would still work-- but not vice versa.

Comment: What are the "the fundamental dependency flaws" in apt-get?

Answer (score 53):

No, `apt-get` is not deprecated. The man page of `apt` has this to say about `apt` vs. `apt-get` (and `apt-cache`):

> SCRIPT USAGE AND DIFFERENCES FROM OTHER APT TOOLS
>
> The apt(8) commandline is designed as an end-user tool and it may change behavior between versions. While it tries not to break
>          backward compatibility this is not guaranteed either if a change seems beneficial for interactive use.
>
> All features of apt(8) are available in dedicated APT tools like apt-get(8) and apt-cache(8) as well.  apt(8) just changes the
>   default
>          value of some options (see apt.conf(5) and specifically the Binary scope). So you should prefer using these commands (potentially
>   with
>          some additional options enabled) in your scripts as they keep backward compatibility as much as possible.

`apt` also gives a warning that says

```
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
```

if it detects there is a pipe. For example:

```
$ apt show python | grep Package

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Package: python
APT-Sources: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

---

As for your questions,

> do i have to replace all apt-get commands with `apt`?

No, you don't have to replace `apt-get` with `apt`. Rather if you were using it in scripts, you should stick to `apt-get` because it has a stable CLI API and guaranteed backward compatibility.

> is `apt-get` dangerous?

`apt` is as dangerous as `apt-get`: you should only install software from sources you trust.

> can i use `apt` in Ubuntu 15.10?

Yup, you can. The problem here is you are still using Ubuntu 15.10, which is now unsupported! Please upgrade to 16.04, which is a LTS version.

> will my programs still work?

By programs, I assume you mean scripts. Yes, they will still work since `apt-get` is not deprecated. In fact, you should prefer to use `apt-get` in scripts for backward compatibility as suggested by `apt`'s man page.

Answer (score 7):

`apt` and `apt-get` are basically the same package manager, what they do is the same.

A difference is that `apt` also contains features from e.g. `apt-cache` and has a nicer looking output.

However, `apt` should not yet be used in scripts, at least if you want to parse its output, because it is still in development and its output format may still change. Bash's tab-autocomplete is also not yet working with many `apt` commands.

You can use both, whichever you prefer.

Comment: apt provides apt-cache features with added delay! try using apt search package and apt-cache search package. Same using policy

Comment: @Anwar I don't see any difference at all using `apt(-cache) policy`. With `apt(-cache) search`, there is a difference in speed, yes, but the output of `apt` is sorted and nicely formatted in return.