# Install google-chrome-stable with apt on 16.04

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, google-chrome

I'm learning about the differences between [apt](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/apt.html) and [apt-get](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/apt-get.html).

I read [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/446484/382864) that they are essentially the same but `apt` aims at providing a more pleasant user experience. Also from reading the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool) it sounds look both tools use the same repositories.

The list are repositories are available in the following [etc](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/etc.html) file:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

Running the following `apt` command seems like another way to simply open that file in a text editor like `vim`:

```
sudo apt edit-sources
```

Now, I'd like install the [`google-chrome-stable`](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/google_chrome/stable/main/base/google-chrome-stable) package. But my goal is to take this as a specific example to help me:

- Learn more about how package management works with on Ubuntu 16.04
- Be able to use `apt` for all my package management needs
- Be able to translate `apt-*` commands into `apt` commands

I'm pretty sure the main problem is the `google-chrome-stable` package lives in a third party repository which isn't inside my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file by default. Also, I think both `apt` and `apt-get` share the same config file. Is this right?

I found [a blog post](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_chrome?dist=stable) that describes how to go through the installation process with `apt-get`:

> Setup key with:
>
> ```
> wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
> ```
>
> Setup repository with:
>
> ```
> sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
> ```
>
> Setup package with:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update 
> sudo apt-get install <package name>
> ```
>
> where  is the name of the package you want to install.

How would I do the same thing with the `apt` command? For example, I see they're `apt-key` and `apt-get`, are there corresponding commands with `apt`?

Edit:

Please refer to the comments below and these two blog posts by [Joel](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/) and [Jeff](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) to learn more about asking specific questions about tools that have been generally asked about.

To add two examples illustrating that this question is more specific:

- Go to the linked question and `ctrl-f` for `config file`. There will be zero results, while in this question and [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/885982/382864) you will find several occurrences.
- Go to the linked question and `ctrl-f` for `apt-key`. There will be zero results, while in this question and [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/885982/382864) you will find several occurrences.

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/q/829864/15003.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between apt and apt-get?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/445384/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-and-apt-get)

Comment: I reference an [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/446484/382864) to a [another question](http://askubuntu.com/q/445384/382864) in my own question. This question isn't a duplicate. It's asking specifically how to solve the problem of installing a third party package using `apt`. It also highlights confusion around the differences between `apt`, `apt-get`, and `apt-key` as well as how the config files are treated. The accepted answer @user535733 links to is essentially a copy and paste of a man page. There are some folks who enjoy and gain from specific examples. That's what this question is about.

Comment: For reference on the issue of having questions about the same tool in different specific contexts please check out these two blog posts by [Joel](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/) and [Jeff](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`apt` and `apt-get` share the same config files. `apt-key` is a separate command, `apt` doesn't have any of `apt-key`'s functionality. The steps from the blog post will remain the same, except that you can replace `apt-get` with `apt` for the last two commands.

It might be easier to just download the Google Chrome package from [its website](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/), and then install it using:

```
sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Chrome's package adds both the key and the repository, so I think this is the simplest way. Note that this wouldn't be directly possible with `apt-get`, since `apt-get` doesn't support installing deb files directly, and if you used `dpkg`, you'd have to run `apt-get install -f` later to fix dependency issues.