# What is the meaning of this sentence regarding the difference between apt-get and apt?

Tags: apt

What is the meaning of the following sentence regarding the difference between apt-get and apt?

> The apt command is meant to be pleasant for end users and does not need to be backward compatible like apt-get(8).

Comment: Is there a particular part of the sentence that is unclear? If it's backward compatibility that is unclear, here's the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_compatibility

Comment: May be relevant: http://askubuntu.com/questions/829864/is-apt-get-deprecated

Comment: The association between "does not need to be" and "backward compatibility" wasn't clear at the moment, but the answer below cleared it out. It is now done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that `apt` and `apt-get` have similar functionality, the difference being that `apt` is intended to be used interactively whereas `apt-get` is supposed to be used in scripts.

The behavior, effect and output of `apt-get` are maintained unchanged (that's what "backward compatible" means), so that scripts can rely on them. `apt` is more free to change with the times and may not function as expected if you run the same script sometime in the future.

Of course, nothing is stopping you from using `apt-get` interactively. I do. Maybe `apt` is easier to use interactively, but two commands are more difficult to learn then one command.

See also "[What is the difference between `apt` and `apt-get`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445384/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-and-apt-get?rq=1)".

Comment: Thank you AlexP. Can you please clarify in the parenthesis level what do you mean by "interactively"? I could put both in a script and run the script (parenthesis block, script file, or heredoc) and both could use me to install something, so it is unclear to me to phrase "interactively" here...

Comment: @Benia: Of course you _can_ use both in scripts; but the developers say that for scripting you _should_ use `apt-get`. The difference is that `apt-get` is guaranteed to remain compatible, that is, newer versions will not change their output or their behavior, whereas `apt` is not -- newer versions may introduce changes. `apt` also is supposed to be easier to use. Of course, in reality people who would benefit from `apt`'s supposed ease of use will prefer graphical utilities...

Comment: *"Of course, in reality people who would benefit from apt's supposed ease of use will prefer graphical utilities..."* Guess I'm an unreal person, then...