# "apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade" not being enough to solve kept back packages problem

Tags: upgrade

A few times, when running `sudo apt-get upgrade`, I've run into the message "The following packages have been kept back:", followed by a list of packages that would not be upgraded. Searching the message online shows that most people solve this by using `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. However, it is sometimes stated that this is a dangerous command, that "[it could leave you with a very broken system](https://askubuntu.com/a/602/377495)". Therefore I've always solved this by performing `sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade` instead. Always... until now. Now I've run into a situation where the first command worked, while the second refused to (i.e., it led to the same "packages have been kept back" problem).

What could be the cause of this? I know that `dist-upgrade` is allowed to remove packages, instead of only being able to install new ones (as the `--with-new-pkgs` flag does). But why would an upgrade need to remove any of my packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is buried in the comments of the posting you linked to:  Sometimes a package is upgraded or changed and this package cannot coexist on the system with a prior version, or with some other package on your computer. " Think of llvm3.6 vs. llvm3.6v5 (with the "v5" meaning that it was compiled with gcc 5). These two cannot co-exist, only either of both can be kept on the system."

As I'm a relative novice, I cannot talk to the veracity of this particular situation *but* I can state that I used to use `dist-upgrade` quite often, and never entered a situation which broke my system.  I also run the most current released version of Ubuntu, and occasionally need to reinstall my system anyhow.

The current flavor of upgrades prefers the `apt` command set as opposed to `apt-get`.  There is some information at [What is the difference between apt and apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445384/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-and-apt-get)

Comment: Why do you occasionally need to reinstall your system? I've never needed that. I only reinstall my system every two years, when a new LTS version of Ubuntu comes out.

Comment: @LGenzelis I'm running the interim releases - currently 17.04 and soon 17.10, and I mess with my system all the time.  Can't help myself.  Sooner or later I bugger stuff up, and I found (on earlier releases) that sometimes the upgrades do not go as well as I would like.