# Is the software updater the same as sudo apt-get upgrade?

Tags: 16.04, update-manager

I have been using Ubuntu for awhile now and have usually used the software updater to update my system. I know that you can use `sudo apt-get upgrade` to update all of your software on your system. What exactly does the software updater do, and is it the same as the aforementioned command?

Comment: The equivalent command(s) are `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` you have to update the list of available software first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know the exact mechanics of software center, but they are all front ends for package management.

From the command line the equivalnts are

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

or

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

I believe Ubuntu is slowly migrating from apt-get to apt.

For additional information see

[What is the difference between apt and apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445384/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-and-apt-get)

https://www.maketecheasier.com/apt-vs-apt-get-ubuntu/

and

https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkgtools.en.html

Comment: Once likely less known diff is starting in 16.04  by default apt will not cache the packages (in /var/cache/apt/archives) while apt-get still does.