# Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution)

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dependencies

After running `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade`,  it seems my install is broken.

```
root@l1k:/home/kali# apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 default-jdk : Depends: default-jdk-headless (= 2:1.8-59) but it is not installed
               Depends: openjdk-8-jdk
 default-jre : Depends: openjdk-8-jre
               Recommends: default-java-plugin but it is not installed
 default-jre-headless : Depends: openjdk-8-jre-headless
 gir1.2-panelapplet-4.0 : Depends: libpanel-applet-4-0 (>= 3.4.1) but it is not installable
 icedtea-6-jre-cacao : Depends: openjdk-6-jre-headless (= 6b35-1.13.7-1~deb7u1)
 libfarstream-0.1-0 : Depends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-good (>= 0.10.29) but it is not installable
 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 : Depends: libpulse0 (= 11.1-3) but 2.0-6.1 is installed
 libpython2.7 : Depends: libpython2.7-stdlib (= 2.7.14-2) but 2.7.9-2 is installed
 libpython2.7-dev : Depends: libpython2.7-stdlib (= 2.7.14-2) but 2.7.9-2 is installed
 libtagc0 : Depends: libtag1c2a (>= 1.6-2~) but it is not installable
 openjdk-6-jre-lib : Depends: openjdk-6-jre-headless (>= 6b27)
 pulseaudio-utils : Depends: libpulse0 (= 11.1-3) but 2.0-6.1 is installed
                    Depends: libpulsedsp but it is not installed
 python2.7-dev : Depends: python2.7 (= 2.7.14-2) but 2.7.9-2 is installed
 vlc-nox : Depends: libtag1c2a (>= 1.7) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So I tried installing some of these dependencies but:

```
root@l1k:/home/kali# apt-get purge default-jdk-headless
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'default-jdk-headless' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 default-jdk : Depends: default-jdk-headless (= 2:1.8-59) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: openjdk-8-jdk
 default-jre : Depends: openjdk-8-jre
               Recommends: default-java-plugin but it is not going to be installed
 default-jre-headless : Depends: openjdk-8-jre-headless
 gir1.2-panelapplet-4.0 : Depends: libpanel-applet-4-0 (>= 3.4.1) but it is not installable
 icedtea-6-jre-cacao : Depends: openjdk-6-jre-headless (= 6b35-1.13.7-1~deb7u1)
 libfarstream-0.1-0 : Depends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-good (>= 0.10.29) but it is not installable
 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 : Depends: libpulse0 (= 11.1-3) but 2.0-6.1 is to be installed
 libpython2.7 : Depends: libpython2.7-stdlib (= 2.7.14-2) but 2.7.9-2 is to be installed
 libpython2.7-dev : Depends: libpython2.7-stdlib (= 2.7.14-2) but 2.7.9-2 is to be installed
 libtagc0 : Depends: libtag1c2a (>= 1.6-2~) but it is not installable
 openjdk-6-jre-lib : Depends: openjdk-6-jre-headless (>= 6b27)
 pulseaudio-utils : Depends: libpulse0 (= 11.1-3) but 2.0-6.1 is to be installed
                    Depends: libpulsedsp but it is not going to be installed
 python2.7-dev : Depends: python2.7 (= 2.7.14-2) but 2.7.9-2 is to be installed
 vlc-nox : Depends: libtag1c2a (>= 1.7) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Even installing new packages is not possible:

```
root@l1k:/home/kali# apt install openjdk-8-jdk-headless
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 default-jdk : Depends: default-jdk-headless (= 2:1.8-59) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: openjdk-8-jdk
 default-jre : Depends: openjdk-8-jre
               Recommends: default-java-plugin but it is not going to be installed
 default-jre-headless : Depends: openjdk-8-jre-headless
 gir1.2-panelapplet-4.0 : Depends: libpanel-applet-4-0 (>= 3.4.1) but it is not installable
 icedtea-6-jre-cacao : Depends: openjdk-6-jre-headless (= 6b35-1.13.7-1~deb7u1)
 libfarstream-0.1-0 : Depends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-good (>= 0.10.29) but it is not installable
 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 : Depends: libpulse0 (= 11.1-3) but 2.0-6.1 is to be installed
 libpython2.7 : Depends: libpython2.7-stdlib (= 2.7.14-2) but 2.7.9-2 is to be installed
 libpython2.7-dev : Depends: libpython2.7-stdlib (= 2.7.14-2) but 2.7.9-2 is to be installed
 libtagc0 : Depends: libtag1c2a (>= 1.6-2~) but it is not installable
 openjdk-6-jre-lib : Depends: openjdk-6-jre-headless (>= 6b27)
 openjdk-8-jdk-headless : Depends: openjdk-8-jre-headless (= 8u151-b12-1)
 pulseaudio-utils : Depends: libpulse0 (= 11.1-3) but 2.0-6.1 is to be installed
                    Depends: libpulsedsp but it is not going to be installed
 python2.7-dev : Depends: python2.7 (= 2.7.14-2) but 2.7.9-2 is to be installed
 vlc-nox : Depends: libtag1c2a (>= 1.7) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: I need to be rude here but you haven't even looked at the error message or ever done a quick search on the Internet. To resolve this issue do exactly what it tells you to try.

  apt --fix-broken install

Comment: In fact you should enter `apt-get --fix-broken install` (not smiply apt..)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Please cv because according to the `root@l1k:/home/kali#` terminal prompt Imme22009 is using Kali Linux and this question is not about Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

I have this problem and I solved with

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

I hope to solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

The answer to each of the three scenarios is contained in the last line of each output:

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

In short, some part of your installation is broken, or *corrupted*, and running the above command will attempt to rectify this issue. You will, probably, be unable to install anything, using `apt`, until you run this command.

As gdoumenc states in [their comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984019/unmet-dependencies-try-apt-fix-broken-install-with-no-packages-or-specify#comment2010405_984019), you could also run

```
apt-get --fix-broken install
```

`apt` is merely a front end for `apt-get`, from [the `apt` man page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984019/unmet-dependencies-try-apt-fix-broken-install-with-no-packages-or-specify#comment2010405_984019):

```
DIFFERENCES TO APT-GET(8)
   The apt command is meant to be pleasant for end users and does not need
   to be backward compatible like apt-get(8).
```

See [What is the difference between apt and apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/q/445384/348964)