# apt gives “Unstable CLI Interface” warning

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management

I am writing a script that needs to read a file containing information of a package for which I wrote this line

```
apt show $PACKAGE_NAME > pack_info.txt
```

However this doesn't creates the `pack_info.txt` file and always gives this Warning :

> WARNING : apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

For the time being I tried redirecting both `STDOUT` & `STDERR` using `&>` and it worked out to give a file `pack_info.txt` that we need.

I also tried getting contents from `dpkg` and that also worked :

```
dpkg -s $PACKAGE_NAME > pack_info.txt
```

What is good that it neither shows a warning nor an error.

What is bad that we don't want to use dpkg and only want STDOUT of apt to redirect to file.

So, I have three Questions to ask :

1. What do we exactly mean by Stable CLI Interface ?
2. How to safely and error-free use such commands in scripts ? 
   [please care to explain with example]
3. Is there a way to only and only redirect STDOUT of `apt show` to a file ?

Answer (score 282, accepted):

`apt` is for the terminal and gives beautiful output while `apt-get` and `apt-cache` are for scripts and give stable, parsable output. The script equivalent of your `apt show` command therefore is:

```
apt-cache show $PACKAGE_NAME >pack_info.txt
```

---

Now to answer your questions one by one:

> What do we exactly mean by Stable CLI Interface?

`apt`'s output is not well usable in scripts. For example, `apt install` (compared to `apt-get install`) displays a progress bar that's useless for scripts and can throw errors when the output is parsed. `apt show firefox` shows a hint for an additional record, which is also totally useless in a script, you want it to simply output *every* record there – that's what `apt-cache show firefox` does. Let's see what `man apt` has to say about that:

> The **apt**(8) commandline is designed as an end-user tool and it may
> change behavior between versions. While it
> tries not to break backward compatibility this is not guaranteed either if a change seems beneficial for
> interactive use.
>
> All features of **apt**(8) are available in dedicated APT tools like **apt-get**(8) and **apt-cache**(8) as well.  **apt**(8)
> just changes the default value of some options (see **apt.conf**(5) and specifically the Binary scope). So you
> should prefer using these commands (potentially with some additional options enabled) in your scripts as they
> keep backward compatibility as much as possible.

---

> How to safely and error-free use such commands in scripts?

Just use `apt-get` or `apt-cache` respectively instead of plain `apt`. :) See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/446484/507051) for a list of equivalents.

---

> Is there a way to only and only redirect STDOUT of apt show to a file?

You did that correctly already: `>file` or `1>file` redirects stdout, `2>file` redirects stderr and `&>file` redirects both to `file`.