# First time writing a script -- why isn't the output going to a file?

Tags: command-line, apt, updates, scripts, log

I learned to use a computer with DOS so I am trying to approximate a batch/.bat file to run all the updates to my system and create a log file of the outcome.

```
#!/bin/bash
#update system in one step
cd ~
date > aupdate.log
echo Launching updates...
echo Beginning apt update
sudo apt update >> aupdate.log
sudo apt upgrade -y >> aupdate.log
echo Completing apt autoremove process
sudo apt autoremove -y >> aupdate.log
echo Beginning snap update
sudo snap refresh >> aupdate.log
echo Beginning flatpak update
flatpak update -y >> aupdate.log
echo Updates complete. Review aupdate.log for details.
```

Am I on the right track? So far I have two problems I need to resolve.

1. No log file is being created
2. How do I suppress the warning about redirecting output when running apt > filename (EDIT: See below)

Edit: This is the result when I run the script:

```
Launching updates...
Beginning apt updates

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.


WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Completing apt autoremove process

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Beginning snap update
All snaps up to date.
Beginning flatpak update
Updates complete. Review aupdate.log for details.
```

EDIT: Based on some early feedback from the comments, I changed the script

```
#!/bin/bash
#update system in one step. Vers 1.1
date > ~/aupdate.log
echo Beginning update...
echo Beginning apt-get updates
apt-get update >> ~/aupdate.log
apt-get upgrade -y >> ~/aupdate.log
echo Completing apt autoremove process
apt-get autoremove -y >> ~/aupdate.log
echo Beginning snap update
snap refresh >> ~/aupdate.log 2>/dev/null
echo Beginning flatpak update
flatpak update -y >> ~/aupdate.log
echo Updates complete. Review aupdate.log for details.
```

Switching to `apt-get` resolved the warning and using `2>/dev/null` with the `snap` line suppressed a snap output I just noticed. I also removed `sudo` from the lines because I run the script as su. **However there's still no log file**

EDIT: This is the result when I run the script now as well as `ls` after.

```
eddie@mrpbell5:~$ sudo ./aupdate.sh
Beginning update...
Beginning apt-get updates
Completing apt autoremove process
Beginning snap update
Beginning flatpak update
Updates complete. Review aupdate.log for details.
eddie@mrpbell5:~$ ls ~ | grep log
eddie@mrpbell5:~$ ls -a
.           .bash_history  .cache      .config    Downloads  .local    Music     .profile  src                        .surfshark  Videos
..          .bash_logout   .cert       Desktop    .gnome     move      Pictures  Public    .ssh                       Templates   .wget-hsts
aupdate.sh  .bashrc        CiscoSpark  Documents  .gnupg     .mozilla  .pki      snap      .sudo_as_admin_successful  .var        .zoom
```

Comment: How do you know the log file is not created? Are you looking in the current directory or in your home directory?

Comment: The best option to remove the `apt` warning is to use `apt-get` instead of `apt`. Alternatively, you can redirect `apt`'s stderr to `/dev/null` using `sudo apt update >> aupdate.log 2>/dev/null`.

Comment: Don't use sudo in scripts :) use sudo to start the script.

Comment: Also, I don't see a reason for using `cd ~`. Just use the path to your log file, for example `sudo apt update >> /path/to/aupdate.log`, or, if you want it in your home, `sudo apt update >> ~/aupdate.log`.

Comment: @glennjackman I checked both. It should be going to the home directory correct?

Comment: @Rinzwind if I run ````sudo ./aupdate.sh```` it wil then run each line as su even without specifying ```sudo``` for that line?

Comment: Use `apt-get` rather than `apt`. Read `man apt-get`.  Also, you're only redirecting STDOUT,  not STDERR. Read `man bash`. Where will `sudo` get its authentication from when the script is run? You're resettling `aupdate.log` every time. Linux isn't DOS.

Comment: @waltinator wait Linux isn't DOS?! You're kidding me! no wonder ````dir /p/l/w```` is always giving me an error! ;-)

Comment: Related [apt gives “Unstable CLI Interface” warning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990823/apt-gives-unstable-cli-interface-warning)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## By `sudo` you become the `root`

I ran your modified script with `sudo ./aupdate.sh`.

The log file is created in the folder `/root/` as I had suspected. This is because, when you execute a command (or a script) with `sudo` the command is executed by the special user `root`. The user `root` has its "home" in a special folder at `/root/`.

## Where should the log go?

You can put the log in your home folder `/home/ehj/`. However, since this is a log of system update activities you may want to keep it in `/var/log/`.

### Sample code

I have added a "environmental variable" in your script to keep the information about the log file.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Location of log
LOG="/var/log/aupdate.log"
#update system in one step. Vers 1.1
date > "$LOG"
echo Beginning update...
echo Beginning apt-get updates
apt-get update >> "$LOG"
apt-get upgrade -y >> "$LOG"
echo Completing apt autoremove process
apt-get autoremove -y >> "$LOG"
echo Beginning snap update
snap refresh >> "$LOG" 2>/dev/null
echo Beginning flatpak update
flatpak update -y >> "$LOG"
echo Updates complete. Review "$LOG" for details.
```

Edit the location of the log file in the line that starts with `LOG=...` to your home folder if you like.

## Other Options

### Unattended Upgrades

The `unattended-upgrades` app usually keeps the security updates up-to-date. However it can be used to keep other apps updated as well. See [How to enable silent automatic updates for any repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87849/how-to-enable-silent-automatic-updates-for-any-repository) for how to set it up.

The `unattended-upgrades` also keeps a log of what it does, much like the log the above script creates.

### Alias

Another approach is to [use the `alias` command](https://linuxhandbook.com/linux-alias-command/) to create an alias for a list of commands. You have to create a file called `/home/$USER/.bash_aliases` with the following content:

```
# My list of aliases
# Note: Since this is called by .bashrc 
# it seems this file does not need to be executable

alias update="sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade && sudo apt -y --purge autoremove"
```

This alias called `update` does not keep log of the updates but does something similar.

Hope this helps

Comment: There it is! Why is it ending up there instead of  ~/ ? is it because /root is ~/ for sudo? how do I fix the output?

Comment: I will complete my answer tomorrow. You are right about the why.

Comment: @EHJ Just give the full path to where you want the output to go, don't use ~

Comment: @user68186 thank you very much for the information! however I am just curious why if I type out the command ````sudo apt update >> aupdate.log```` it goes to /home but if I run the script it goes to /root... why is that?

Comment: @EHJ That is a very good question. I don't know the answer yet. Please ask a new question, so that others with more knowledge can answer it. This may be due to the difference in the environmental settings in the terminal as compared with the bash.