# I got apt error during executing commands

Tags: apt, ruby-on-rails

I tried to execute the following command but i got below error

```
sudo apt-get apt install -y ruby-dev nodejs postgresql-client redis-server wkhtmltopdf memcached
```

> E: Invalid operation apt

Comment: You're repeating apt 2 times, use: `sudo apt install -y ruby-dev nodejs postgresql-client redis-server wkhtmltopdf memcached` instead

Answer (score 2):

You're using `apt` and `apt-get` together, which does not work. You should either use `sudo apt` or `sudo apt-get`.

So the correct command is:

```
sudo apt install -y ruby-dev nodejs postgresql-client redis-server wkhtmltopdf memcached`
```

For more details about `apt` and `apt-get` check their manpages (`man apt`, `man apt-get`) and check this question too: [what is the difference between apt and apt-get](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445384/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-and-apt-get)