# What is the difference between `apt upgrade` and `apt-get full upgrade`? Is the later one not suggested to use?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, update-manager

Recently when I was trying to update my Ubuntu, I initially used the commands:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Then, I thought my system is full updated (i.e., with system and security updates), but gradually I found that Ubuntu was still prompting for certain updates, and those were actually the system updates. Proceeding, I read some discussions online, and started using,

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get full-upgrade`

This also downloaded certain files like:

```
linux-headers-generic 

linux-image-generic
```

etc.

Yesterday, someone suggested me to use:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt upgrade`

instead, since, it was mentioned that, `apt-get full-upgrade` might cause error and is dangerous, for it can lead to deletion of necessary packages if the package system is "messed-up".

Now, I am a bit confused, and feels like to start over again.

Which command set should I use to get full system and security updates, and what is the actual difference between `apt-get full-upgrade` and `apt upgrade`. Is the former shouldn't be really put to use?

Comment: Actually the two set of commands I mentioned are bit different. Need specific clarifications on that. Besides, I've read that article too, but sorry no.

Comment: Your line `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt upgrade` contains two commands (the `&&` means the second command is only executed if the first completes without errors) to you might need to clarify which **two** you mean.  The link I selected mentions `update`,  `upgrade` and `dist-upgrade` (or `full-upgrade` in `apt` usage..) - refer to `man` or manual pages for exact details on your release, as there is *very slight* variation on release  (*more functionality gets added to `apt` over time, so there is less need for `apt-get` very slowly*)

Comment: Carefully analyse the question, it's the difference between `apt-get full-upgrade` and `apt upgrade`.

Comment: refer duplicate - it covers `update`, `upgrade`, `dist-upgrade` & `full-upgrade`.  As stated there is slight variations as `apt` gets improved over time (ie. release specific), so read `man apt` for details for your unstated release.  Personally I use `full-upgrade` (or `dist-upgrade`) unless I have specific reason to limit upgrade to those provided by `upgrade`

Comment: `man apt` tells me "*full-upgrade performs the function of upgrade but will remove currently installed packages if this is needed to upgrade the system as a whole*" for my release.. the approximately similar detail found in my *duplicate* tagged post (variation will exist on release)

Comment: `apt` is a nicer replacement for `apt-get`.   It however is a different tool, which does thing differently.  The purpose of the commands is `apt-get update` is replaced by `apt update`, `apt-get upgrade` is replaced by `apt upgrade`, `apt-get dist-upgrade` is replaced by `apt-get full-upgrade` etc... the same options to ease transition, however `apt-get` still does things `apt` cannot do, why `apt` changes with releases...  `apt` is a wrapper that does almost the same as `apt-get` so you're mixing two different tools in a way that isn't wise!!  `apt` will likely replace `apt-get`

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/questions/445384/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-and-apt-get

Comment: ok, just tell me in comments, what should I use. apt upgrade or apt-get full-upgrade. Is that later really dangerous?

Comment: No it's not dangerous..   It's only a problem for people because they've already damaged their system (like using `sudo apt autoremove` can mean prior damage becomes readily apparent, though it didn't actually do the damage, it was prior careless commands). Problems if they occur were waiting to happen, and any mistakes were from prior commands in my opinion...