# How do repositories work?

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, repository

Alright, so I just installed Ubuntu and I'm new to the Linux community in general so this might seem a bit obvious to most of you, but how do repositories work? I know that a repository is like a server that has a bunch of packages that you can install from but I'm still confused on many aspects of this concept, here are a few of them:

1. What is apt. I did some googling and its a command utility. So is it just a piece of software for handling repositories?
2. What is the difference between apt and apt-get?
3. There seems to this "Ubuntu software center", which repository is that? Is it like Ubuntu's official repository? Or is it a collection of all the repositories on your computer?
4. How do you search for a package without using the Ubuntu software center (if it's even possible)?
5. When you use apt for installing packages from a third party repository, it doesn't seem like you need to specify which repository. Thus it seems like when you add a repository, it all gets added to this one big abstract repository. Won't that cause name conflicts?
6. When you want to add a repository, it seems that you can do something like this, sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java How does apt locate that repository? There doesn't seem to be a URL of any sort.

I know this is a lot of questions but if you could answer even 1 or 2 that'd be really helpful. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. Please see the site help for how to ask questions here.

Comment: Your second question is already answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/445384/590937).

Comment: Judicious use of any Search Engine will lead you to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(software), which will answer many of your questions.

Comment: #5 - why would you add an additional repository if the software you want is already available from your current repos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is apt. I did some googling and its a command utility. So is it just a piece of software for handling repositories? What is the difference between apt and apt-get?

Advanced packaging tool or `apt` for short is a tool to manipulate the .deb packages on your system or to be installed on your system. The `apt-get` is the old name for the new `apt` command, they are the same command. Then there is `aptitude` and `dpkg` that can do the same job and install/manipulate packages. The `dpkg` being the original tool with `apt-get` coming next then the `aptitude` in terms of their development.

> There seems to this "Ubuntu software center", which repository is that? Is it like Ubuntu's official repository? Or is it a collection of all the repositories on your computer?

Both it will have all applications available in the repositories contained in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and the files contained in the `/etc/apt/sources.d/`. The directory being a new idea for easily adding a repository without editing the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. And it is where they prefer you install it from, their "official" place for installation of software.

> How do you search for a package without using the Ubuntu software center (if it's even possible)?

In the `Terminal` application `apt-cache search package_name` will do a search of the cache for your package. Want to see the version to be installed `apt-cache policy package_name` will show you the version installed if any, the versions available, the repository it comes from and if any newer version is available.

> When you use apt for installing packages from a third party repository, it doesn't seem like you need to specify which repository. Thus it seems like when you add a repository, it all gets added to this one big abstract repository. Won't that cause name conflicts?

No there are strict naming practices for packages designed to avoid this conflict , in addition they have version number added onto to the to further allow packages to co-exist. When a repository is added you must make certain it is made for the version of the OS it runs on.

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free
```

Above is a line for `Debian Buster` it shows you the repository in the name, it could be `stable` too as that is the status of `Buster` until the next release in a month or two. When new stable is released the distribution would be updated if you had `stable` for your line and not `Buster`.

> When you want to add a repository, it seems that you can do something like this, sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java How does apt locate that repository? There doesn't seem to be a URL of any sort.

I have no clue on how Ubuntu's system for that works I just use it when necessary and am too lazy to edit the file myself.

Comment: For the last question, PPAs are hosted at https://launchpad.net. (The PPA for your specific example is https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team, and Ubuntu is at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu). So the "ppa:" format is simply converted to a full URL starting with "https://launchpad.net".