# Aptitude progress bar

Tags: aptitude

## Discription

### How to enable progress bar in aptitude

HI guys,im now using aptitude for installation,in apt there's a progress bar on the foot of my console,but in aptitude there's no such thing,i want to enable or make it in aptitude...any solutions?

Comment: See also: [What is the difference between apt and apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445384/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-and-apt-get)

Answer (score 0):

### `aptitude`

[Aptitude](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/aptitude) shows its progress by text - in percents when you use it from terminal by for example

> ```
> $ sudo aptitude install octave
> ...
> 51% [111 libjaxb-java 619 kB/1 965 kB 31%]                                                    > ...
> ```

In TUI interactive mode (i.e. started by `sudo aptitude`) it has progress bar labeled *Total Progress* when it downloads and installs things, this means after selecting packages to install/remove and then pressing `<g>`, `<g>` as shown on image:

> [image: Aptitude]

If you need more - write feature request to developer.

### `apt-get`

To track progress `apt-get` you can use special option named `--show-progress`. See it in action below:

> [image: apt-get progress]

### `apt`

The `apt` already has *Progress* bar with percents on the bottom of the screen:

> [image: apt progress]

---

Manuals to read:

- [`man aptitude`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/aptitude-curses.8.html)
- [`man apt-get`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/apt-get.8.html)
- [`man apt`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/apt.8.html)

Comment: I mean when doing dpkg job it won't display the bar