# What is the difference between sudo apt-get install and sudo apt install

Tags: apt, package-management

I installed many packages from `sudo apt-get install` but when I typed  `sudo apt --help` it gave a direct option of doing installation by `sudo apt install [package name]`... So, what is the difference between the two ? are there any issues if I don't use 'get' along with 'apt'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between apt and apt-get?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/445384/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-and-apt-get)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Not much. `apt` is a new command that supposed to merge several functions from `apt-get` and `apt-cache` into one command. It's still a little rough around the edges but here's the command listing from `--help`:

```
Basic commands: 
 list - list packages based on package names
 search - search in package descriptions
 show - show package details

 update - update list of available packages

 install - install packages
 remove  - remove packages

 upgrade - upgrade the system by installing/upgrading packages
 full-upgrade - upgrade the system by removing/installing/upgrading packages

 edit-sources - edit the source information file
```

The equivalent functions are designed to work in similar ways but it's not a proxy command (it's not calling the old ones - it's a new interface directly onto the Apt libraries) so there may be some edge-case changes.

There are also some obvious omissions (`download`, `policy`, etc) that power-users will miss and there are a whole raft of undocumented commands (`purge` still works but I can't find anything on it).

**16.04 Update:** A lot of the omissions have now been included but aren't yet documented, nor do they have Bash-completions. It's a shame it's taking this long to implement functionality that already exists in the codebase but oh well. My advice is that if you're used to an `apt-{get,cache}` command, try it on `apt`. It might work.

---

There's also a `DIFFERENCES TO APT-GET(8)` section in the `man apt` page that's interesting:

```
   The apt command is meant to be pleasant for end users and does
   not need to be backward compatible like apt-get(8). Therefore
   some options are different:

   ·   The option DPkgPM::Progress-Fancy is enabled.

   ·   The option APT::Color is enabled.

   ·   A new list command is available similar to dpkg --list.

   ·   The option upgrade has --with-new-pkgs enabled by default.
```

---

And if you want Bash-completions, I've had [an attempt as writing a completions file](https://askubuntu.com/q/445637/449) for it already. These are included with later Ubuntu installs.

Comment: How about `aptitude`?

Comment: That's from a completely different codebase. Functionally it will also automatically autoremove after doing package operations.