# Where are changelogs for updates to "apt"?

Tags: apt

Today, I received updates including an update to the `apt` package.

```
Start-Date: 2016-04-07  06:33:13
Commandline: apt-get dist-upgrade
Upgrade: apt:amd64 (1.0.1ubuntu2.11, 1.0.1ubuntu2.12), apt-transport-https:amd64 (1.0.1ubuntu2.11, 1.0.1ubuntu2.12), apt-utils:amd64 (1.0.1ubuntu2.11, 1.0.1ubuntu2.12), libapt-inst1.5:amd64 (1.0.1ubuntu2.11, 1.0.1ubuntu2.12), apt-doc:amd64 (1.0.1ubuntu2.11, 1.0.1ubuntu2.12), libapt-pkg4.12:amd64 (1.0.1ubuntu2.11, 1.0.1ubuntu2.12)
End-Date: 2016-04-07  06:33:39
```

`man apt` tells me that ...

> apt (Advanced Package Tool) is the command-line tool for handling
>         packages. It provides a commandline interface for the package management
>         of the system. See also apt-get(8) and apt-cache(8) for more low-level
>         command options.

However, I would like to know what changes have been made **in this version** (and subsequent versions) that may affect my usage of the package. Where can I find such information?

I have already read several older sources of information including [Oli's comprehensive answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/481244/248158).

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
$ sudo apt-get changelog apt > ~/apt-changelog
[sudo] password for dkbose: 
Get:1 Changelog for apt (http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.12/changelog) [439 kB]
Fetched 439 kB in 4s (92.1 kB/s)
$
```

A second way:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-listchanges
```

But `apt-listchanges` will work for **all** *subsequent* installs made using APT, not just for a specific package.

A third way is to examine `/usr/share/doc/libapt-pkg4.12/changelog.gz`.

Comment: `/usr/share/doc/apt/changelog.gz` is simpler, and works on all systems. ;)