# Why Does Software Updater Say No updates Available, but apt-get upgrade Shows updates available?

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager

I normally use Software Updater to keep the system updated. However I occasionally will run apt-get upgrade from the terminal and I've notice there are times when Software Updater says there are no available updates but apt-get update shows some updates to packages.

I haven't been able to figure out why.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> StableReleaseUpdates will no longer appear in update-manager at the same time for all machines. Instead a subset of machines will be selected at random to receive the update first. The update will only be made available to everyone if there are no serious regressions encountered by the first set of users. There is still a testing process completed by Ubuntu developers before any users receive the update.

Source: [PhasedUpdates](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PhasedUpdates) and [Brian’s Blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20200813204126/http://www.murraytwins.com/blog/?p=127).

[Prior to Ubuntu 21.04](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/phased-updates-in-apt-in-21-04/20345), if you update via the terminal, you bypass the phased update system and will get all updates as soon as they're released. Read the comments in Brian's Blog for how to opt out of phased updates if you wish.

Comment: Is there a way to never be in that group and let everyone else be the guinea pig :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know. The only choices seem to be to get updates as soon as possible (via apt-get update/upgrade/dist-upgrade) or be offered updates early depending on whether your machine is chosen at random.